# What does '//' mean in return from `which`

Tags: shell, path, slash, which

I have an executable script `test` under the full path `/home/sawa/foo/bar/test`. The directory `/home/sawa/foo/bar` is within `$PATH`, and has priority over the default ones including `/usr/bin`. When I do

```
`which test`
```

to see whether this command is correctly recognized, it returns

```
/home/sawa/foo/bar//test
```

with the double slash `//`. I know that there is a built in command with the same name `test`, and when I remove mine, this one under `/usr/bin/test` is returned by `which`, so I think it's interfering in some way.

1. What does this double slash mean here, and why is it appearing here?
2. My executable `test` does not seem to work correctly. Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would guess that you have `/home/sawa/foo/bar/` on your path - i.e. a path with a trailing slash.

`which` is iterating over each element of `$PATH` and appending `/argv[1]` and checking for the existence of that file. That causes a double-slash - one from the `$PATH` part, and one from `/argv[1]`.

A [double-slash is no problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11964/1925). It is collapsed to a single slash by the kernel. Only at the beginning of a path may a double-slash have special meaning, and not always then.

As for `test` not working, ensure you are not using the shell built-in when calling `test`. You usually do this by using a full path, but with bash you can also use `enable -n test` to disable the built-in `test` command.

Comment: Thanks. That's the perfect answer that I wanted. It helps.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely it doesn't work for you because the shell builtin is getting executed with priority over any executable. You should not knowingly create a name conflict like this, behavior *will* be inconsistent across environments. The system binary `test` is only there for the use of shells that don't have a builtin version.

If you want alternate functionality, you should name your script something else.

Comment: That advice given, I don't actually know what `//` represents here so it will be interesting to hear from somebody who does :)