# Building paths robustly

Tags: shell-script

Say I have several variables in a shell script (e.g. in zsh):

```
FOLDER_1, FOLDER_2, etc.
```

These variables refer to folders descending from `/`. For example, if I have a path `/home/me/stuff/items`

the variables would be:

```
FOLDER_1='home'
FOLDER_2='me'
FOLDER_3='stuff'
```

Now, say that I want to build back the corresponding path by concatenating the variables. One possible way is to build the path as follows:

```
PATH=$FOLDER_1/$FOLDER_2/$FOLDER_3/
```

However, say that some of the variables `FOLDER_i` come with trailing forward slashes, while others don't (and we don't know which) e.g.

```
FOLDER_1='home'
FOLDER_2='stuff/'
FOLDER_3='items'
```

My question is: **How could I build the path robustly?** (e.g. avoiding double slashes, and adding them where they need to be).

I thought one way to do this is to add the `/` always between pairs of variables, and then delete any duplicates with `sed`, but I can't make it to work (I am not sure I am handling `/` correctly in `sed`).

Also, **am I reinventing the wheel**? (i.e. is there any built-in that does this already?).

Finallly, if the variables are in an **array**, e.g. `FOLDERS`, would it be possible to do this without looping? (or alternatively, by looping but without knowing how many `FOLDERS` there are in the array).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `printf` with an array:

```
parts=("$FOLDER_1" "$FOLDER_2" "$FOLDER_3");
printf '/%s' "${parts[@]%/}"
# Use "printf -v path" to save it into a variable called "path" instead of printing it
```

The `%` operator trims trailing strings, in this case `/`. By applying it to `parts[@]`, it trims each array member separately.

The key to understanding this `printf` trick, is this bit from `man 1 printf`: "The format string is reused as often as necessary to satisfy the arguments."

Comment: The single `%` method works for the single trailing slash mentioned in the queston. To cater for when there are multiple slashes, `${parts[@]%%/*}` works. Here is a link to a bit more info on the slash issue: [What do double slashes mean in UNIX path? Is 'cd dir/subdir// valid](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11964/what-do-double-slashes-mean-in-unix-path-is-cd-dir-subdir-valid)...

Comment: @fered: `/*` in this case does *not* mean zero or more *slashes*, but rather a slash followed by any number of characters. That means if your path starts with a slash, the result will be the empty string!

Comment: I had considered, as per the example, that there would only be trailing slashes. However, to adapt to the possibility of a leading slash(es), bash's `extglob` (with regex) can by used.. `shopt -s extglob; ${parts[@]%%/+(/)}` ...

Comment: For the sake of completeness, could you modify / add to this code example such that the result of the `printf` command is also stored in a variable? I think that this would be useful to quite a few people reading this answer.

Answer (score 19):

The simple answer is to stop worrying and love multiple slashes. [Multiple slashes have the same effect as a single slash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file/1919#1919) (except that a path beginning with `//` has a different meaning on a few systems; unix emulation layers on Windows are the only ones I can name). That's by design, and being able to assemble file names without having to worry about multiple slashes was a major part of that design decision.

To join array elements, in zsh, you can use the `j` [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags).

```
dir=${(j:/:)FOLDERS}
```

You can squish the duplicate slashes while you're at it, but that's purely cosmetic.

```
setopt extended_glob
dir=${${(j:/:)FOLDERS}//\/\/##/\/}
```

In ksh and bash, you can join an array using the first character of `$IFS` as a separator. You can then squish the duplicate slashes. In bash, you'll need to do `shopt -s extglob` to enable the ksh globs in the last line of the snippet below.

```
IFS=/
dir="${FOLDERS[*]}"
unset IFS
dir=${dir//\/+(\/)//}
```

Answer (score 3):

How is `sed` not working for you?  Try `sed 's|/\+|/|g'` after concatenating, or `sed 's|/||g'` before.

Answer (score 1):

`bash 4` introduced  extended globbing, which enables regular expression matching in parameter substitution `${var....}` ... It is turned off by default. To enable it for your script, simply set the shell option *extglob*...

Assuming that *$dir* == `/home/me/////////stuff//items`

```
shopt -s extglob; dir="${dir//+(\/)//}"
```

Resulting value of *$dir*

```
/home/me/stuff/items
```

Here are some examples with do-s and-don't-s -- [Bash Extended Globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing)