# Should I use a slash at the end of path variables in shell script or not?

Tags: shell, shell-script

Today when writing my shell script.

A question suddenly comes to my mind.

Since `cd /target_dir` and `cd /target_dir/` both works.
Should I add a slash at the end of my path variables in a shell script?
Such as `LOG_PATH=/data/nginx/logs` versus `LOG_PATH=/data/nginx/logs/`.

I did some gross search on google, but didn't find discussion about this, maybe it's too basic?

For now, it's really hard for me to decide which style to pick.
But I preferred `LOG_PATH=/target_dir/` style a bit more.
Because when I'm doing autocompletion with bash, it pops me the result with slash.

What's your opinion about this, why?

Comment: relevant: [should a directory path variable end with a trailing slash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980255/should-a-directory-path-variable-end-with-a-trailing-slash) (SO) a little less: [building paths robustly](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23208/building-paths-robustly)

Comment: There is no rule. Both coding style has some advantages and some drawback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to POSIX:

> Definition of a pathname:
>
> A string that is used to identify a file. It has optional beginning *< slash >* characters, followed by zero or more filenames separated by *< slash >* characters. **A pathname can optionally contain one or more trailing *< slash >* characters.** Multiple successive *< slash >* characters are considered to be the same as one *< slash >*, except for the case of exactly two leading *< slash >* characters.

Comment: @It's interesting, that I can cd to `//` and `/` with their name show differently on the bash prompt, and using `pwd` I'll get different path showed, but their content are identical! Why?

Comment: @Zen http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12291/70524

Comment: Because `bash` tracks the current directory in a very naive way, as a string. It just appends and removes from the path heuristically, it does not link to the actual filesystem. One consequence is that you can cd into a symbolic link and come back the same way (if bash didn't decide it was too much and reinitialized it). The other is what you describe. You should not rely on the shell's tracking of the current directory, it is unreliable.

Comment: Related: [Strange difference between pwd and /bin/pwd](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145479/80216).

Answer (score 8):

To be on the safe side, include the slash. This can lead to multiple slashes when concatenating the paths, but at least you avoid problems.

A few examples: `rsync` treats paths differently if the trailing slash is included (it synchronizes *that* directory instead of making another subdirectory). Symbolic links to directories sometimes behave in an unexpected way when they don't have the trailing slash - at least shell completion gets confused. You never know if the command/script you invoke relies on checking for the slash for some special behaviour. It could even save you from overwriting something. For instance, if you have a file named `foo`, but you mistakenly think it's a directory and want to move something in it, then `mv bar foo` will overwrite the file (data loss, potential catastrophe) but `mv bar foo/` will just complain and do nothing.

So to conclude, it most cases it doesn't matter, but you should use the slash to protect yourself, and also to make it more obvious to the human reader what you intended to do in a script. A casual observer will immediately be sure that a variable refers to a directory if it ends with a slash, and will use it correctly if it needs to be modified.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not. It adds an extra unnecessary slash (`/`).

**example**

say you want to export java's `bin` directory to your `PATH` variable ,

`export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jre1.7.0_45/bin/`

now check it,

```
user@host:~$ which java
/opt/jre1.7.0_45/bin//java
```

notice the extra slash (`/`) before java, but fortunately it just works in such case.

Comment: I saw in this link there is a 31 votes answer in which the author thinks we should add a slash. I'm confused. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980255/should-a-directory-path-variable-end-with-a-trailing-slash

Comment: @Zen, yes I checked it, It was on the first comment of your question. Thanks.

Comment: Better two slashes than none. This one is ugly but safe... the other option is way worse and can be dangerous.