# Why does cd // work?

Tags: bash, osx, darwin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unix, difference between path starting with '/' and '//'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and)

On my Mac OS X Lion box, with Bash:

```
$ cd //
$ pwd
//
$ ls
Applications    System      cores      mach_kernel    sbin
Developer       Users       dev        net            tmp
Library         Volumes     etc        opt            usr
Network         bin         home       private        var
```

This has to be some mysterious backwards-compatibility thing, but what is it?