# "cd //" and "cd /" what is the difference?

Tags: bash, shell, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unix, difference between path starting with '/' and '//'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and)

If I make a `cd //` followed by a `pwd` I see:

```
# cd //
# pwd
//
```

why is that? what's the differece with:

```
cd /
pwd
/
```

Everything looks the same to me...

Comment: Even scarier, `cd ///` and more go back to giving `/`, so I suspect there's some special handling for `//` in the builtin pwd(`/bin/pwd` works as expected).

Comment: Duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12283/7285

Comment: @Ulrich Have you tried with 2+ slashes? It behaves like the single slash... isn't it scary too?!