# Bash function to scp a file not working

Tags: bash, scp, function

I wrote the following bash function:

```
function to_company() 
{
    scp ${1} username@long.server.name.company.com://home/username 
}
```

When I do:

```
$ to_company code_diff.txt
```

It asks for password and then fails with following message:

```
scp: //home/username: not a regular file
```

I tried giving `//home/username/` & `//home/username/${1}` in the script but got the same result.

If I manually execute above command and pass `code_diff.txt` in place of `${1}`, file is transferred without issues.

What mistake am I making?

Comment: Always quote your variables in shell !

Comment: @sputnick, I changed the variable to `"$1"` instead of `${1}`, but got the same result.

Comment: I just tried this and it worked for me. I would drop the `//home` and make it `/home`, not that I think it matters, but it might. Do you have read access on the file you're attempting to copy?

Comment: For testing, can you add a `echo` before your scp and check the output?

Comment: @slm, @Drav Sloan, using `/home` instead of `//home` worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that was the issue. In general I usually use a tilde (`~`) such as this: `scp file user@mach:~/some/dir/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that it should matter, but the remote path should be `/home/username` (single forward slash). And as sputnick pointed out, quote your `${1}` with `"${1}"`.

I've copied the same command and it works when I test it, so I suspect (given the "not a regular file" error) that you have an extra space between `username@long.server.name.company.com:` and `//home/username`.

Another thing to try is to add debugging (by supplying `-v` on the scp command) and see 
if that gives any clues:

```
function to_company() 
{
    scp -v "${1}" username@long.server.name.company.com:/home/username 
}
```

Comment: Another thought is that you have `scp` aliased, what does `type scp` say?

Comment: Single forward slash solved. Thank you. How do I add debugging? By putting in echo statements?

Comment: Sorry I didnt make that clear, use `-v` on the scp (I'll make that clearer in my answer).

Comment: Would you know why using double slash in script/function fails but when executing it manually works fine?

Comment: I'm surprised it does to be honest, does the `-v` on the scp shed any light on the problem?

Comment: My script is now working with double slash and with single slash as well. I used `-v` to trace root cause but never hit the same error again. I am using GNU bash 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12). I really don't know why it started working for both slashes.

Comment: @Bhaskar - when I tried this the double slashes worked for me too. In Unix you can usually specify paths using multiple slashes such as `/home///sam`. They are just ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You're approaching this the wrong way. Instead of writing a shell wrapper, define a host alias in your `~/.ssh/config`.

```
Host work
Hostname long.server.name.company.com
User bob
```

Then, to copy a file to your company's server:

```
scp filename.ext work:
```

The remote path is relative to your home directory, so `work:` means the same thing as `work:/home/username`.

---

Your function fails if you pass an argument that contains whitespace or globbing characters `\[?*`. That's easily fixed by putting the parameter expansion in double quotes: `"$1"`. [Always put double quotes around variable and command substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary/68748#68748).

Another potential problem is that `//` at the beginning of a path may be interpreted specially. Normally consecutive slashes in a path are equivalent to one slash, but [a path that begins with exactly two slashes has a special meaning on some systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and/12291#12291).

Comment: Excellent, this is the solution I needed; much better than mucking around with bash aliases. I'll note though, that this solution didn't work for me as-is; for whatever reason, I had to change `Username` to `User`, as for me, `Username` was not a recognized ssh configuration option.