# Strange difference between pwd and /bin/pwd

Tags: shell, symlink, pwd

I added a symlink to the current directory with `ln -s . aa`. If I execute `cd aa`, and after that I executed `pwd`, the response is `/home/sim/aa`.

But if I execute `/bin/pwd` it prints `/home/sim` (the current directory hasn't changed).

Where does this difference come from?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In most shells including bash, `pwd` is a shell builtin:

```
$ type -a pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
pwd is /bin/pwd
```

If you use `/bin/pwd`, you must use the `-L` option to get the same result as builtin `pwd`:

```
$ ln -s . test
$ cd test && pwd
/home/cuonglm/test
$ /bin/pwd
/home/cuonglm
$ /bin/pwd -L
/home/cuonglm/test
```

By default, `/bin/pwd` ignores symlinks and prints the actual directory.

From [`info pwd`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/pwd-invocation.html):

```
`-L'
`--logical'
     If the contents of the environment variable `PWD' provide an
     absolute name of the current directory with no `.' or `..'
     components, but possibly with symbolic links, then output those
     contents.  Otherwise, fall back to default `-P' handling.

`-P'
`--physical'
     Print a fully resolved name for the current directory.  That is,
     all components of the printed name will be actual directory
     names--none will be symbolic links.
```

The built-in `pwd` includes symlink by default, except that `-P` option is used, or `-o physical` set builtin is enabled.

From [`man bash`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

```
pwd [-LP]
              Print the absolute pathname of the  current  working  directory.
              The pathname printed contains no symbolic links if the -P option
              is supplied or the -o physical option to the set builtin command
              is  enabled.  If the -L option is used, the pathname printed may
              contain symbolic links.  The return status is 0 unless an  error
              occurs  while  reading  the  name of the current directory or an
              invalid option is supplied.
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand where does come from those differences

Comment: `/bin/pwd` ignores symlink by default, read part `info pwd` in my answer: Print a fully resolved name for the current directory.  That is,
     all components of the printed name will be actual directory
     names--**none will be symbolic links.**

Comment: @user3581976: See my updated for more clearly.

Comment: Why is there a -L command for pwd although it is set by default? And doesn't the shell use the /bin/pwd command to run pwd?

Comment: @user3581976: Please read the manpage carefully. `/bin/pwd` use `-P` option by default. And builtin command has higher precedence than command in system `$PATH`.

Comment: I didn't say /bin/pwd, I said pwd...

Comment: @user3581976: Image that you start your shell with `set -o physical`, now `pwd` is use `-P` option by default, if you don't have `-L` option, how do you print the path contains symlink? Read this `https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html` to know what `set -o physical` does.

Comment: @user3581976: Do you understand what a “builtin command” is? It means that all processing to execute the command is ***built in*** to the shell, so it can do it *without* using an external program. So, in answer to your question “And doesn't the shell use the `/bin/pwd` command to run `pwd`?”, the answer is an emphatic ***No!***

Answer (score 8):

It is possible for a process to interrogate the file system
to determine its current working directory, using a method that’s a little too complicated
to be on topic as an answer to this question. 
This is what the `pwd` program and the `getcwd` library function do. 
In the early days of Unix,
they were the only ways to find out what your working directory was. 
Here’s the part of the answer to your question that I can’t find
in any of the other answers,
or even anywhere else on this site (after 42 seconds’ worth of searching):

- When the shell starts, it gets its current working directory
  (probably by calling `getcwd`).
- Thereafter, whenever you do a `cd`, `pushd`, or `popd`,
  the shell *keeps track* of the working directory using string manipulation functions.
  For example,

  - If your working directory is `/home/sim` and you type `cd ..`,
    the shell computes that your working directory is `/home`.
  - If your working directory is `/home/sim` and you type `cd .`,
    the shell computes that your working directory is still `/home/sim`.
  - If your working directory is `/home/sim` and you type `cd aa`,
    the shell computes that your working directory is `/home/sim/aa` –
    without checking to see whether `aa` is a symbolic link.

  It does this to save the “cost” of calling `getcwd`. 
  But this is a trade-off, since it can result in incorrect information.
- The `pwd` (builtin) command simply displays the shell’s remembered/computed notion
  of what the working directory is.
- Also, the shell puts its remembered/computed notion of what the working directory is
  into the PWD environment variable, for the *convenience* of user processes. 
  A process should never rely on this if it wants accurate information.

So, the bottom line is that the shell can get confused about where it is. 
But if you type `/bin/pwd`, that runs in a separate process
that doesn’t have access to the shell’s notion of what the working directory is,
and so it determines the true working directory itself, the old-fashioned way. 
(Exception: the `/bin/pwd` program *can* look at the PWD environment variable,
and apparently it does when you specify `-L`.) 
Here’s another example of how the shell can get confused:

> `cd /home/sim/aa         #` Assume that `/home`,  `/home/sim`,  and `/home/sim/aa`
>                           `#` are all real directories (not symbolic links).
>   `pwd                     #` Output: `/home/sim/aa`, which is correct.
>   `mv ../aa ../bb`
>   `pwd                     #` Output: `/home/sim/aa`, which is incorrect.
>   `/bin/pwd                #` Output: `/home/sim/bb`, which is correct.

---

And, just in case you’re not clear on this, if you type `ln -s . aa` and `cd aa`,
then your current working directory ***hasn’t changed***, any more than it does
when you type `cd .` – because, that’s essentially what you’re doing when you type `cd aa`.

Comment: Thanks, very good answer, this is what I was waiting for ;)

Comment: This answer seems a little *bent*. There's more to `-L` than *saving cost* - and `$PWD` is a user-defined POSIX-specified environment variable - user-space applications should probably *trust it* *(whatever that means...?)*. Anyway, while I'm not at all a fan of symlinks, it is the user's prerogative to indirect in as many crazy directions as he or she should choose with them - and that's what `-L` is about more than anything.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (the symbolic links aren't the point of the question).

Comment: This is more helpful than the accepted answer IMO. So /bin/pwd is like the true working directory, whereas pwd just shows you your working directory relative to where you started the shell?