# copy files from the parent location when I am inside a symbolically linked folder

Tags: symlink, cp, directory-structure, pwd

Suppose I have created two folders in `/tmp` called `parent` and `child`. `child` contains a file called `test-child.txt` and `parent` contains a file called `test-parent.txt`. Now let's go inside the `parent` and create a symbolic link to the `child`. Next, go inside the `child` and try to copy the `test-parent.txt` from the `parent`. The bash completion works but the actual file copy fails --

```
cd /tmp
pwd
/tmp
mkdir parent
mkdir child
touch child/test-child.txt
ls child/
test-child.txt
cd parent
ln -sf ../child .
touch test-parent.txt
cd child
cp ../test-parent.txt .
cp: cannot stat ‘../test-parent.txt’: No such file or directory
```

why ??

Moreover, when I am inside `child` and if I say --

```
pwd
/tmp/parent/child
```

Comment: You may find [Strange difference between `pwd` and `/bin/pwd`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145479/23408) to be relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shells keep track of symbolic links as a convenience for users. This has the nice effect that `cd foo && cd ..` always goes back to the original directory, even when `foo` is a symbolic link to a directory. It has two kinds of downsides: the main one is that other programs don't behave this way; additionally, symbolic directory tracking introduces problems of its own (what happens when the symbolic link changes? what happens if the process doesn't have the permission to read the symlink? etc.).

Shells can only do this because they keep track of all directory changes, so they remember how you got there. When a new process starts, it doesn't get this historical information. Under the hood, it finds where it is by moving upwards from the current directory, following `..` links until it hits the root¹.

If you reached a directory through symbolic links, you can print out a symlink-less path with the [`pwd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pwd) builtin, by calling `pwd -P`. If you call another program from the shell, don't pass it a path that contains `..` after symlink components, as the program would interpret it differently. Instead, eliminate the `..` components by calling `pwd -P`:

```
cp "$(cd .. && pwd -P && echo /)test-parent.txt" .
```

If you want to forget about symlinks used in past `cd` commands in a shell session, you can run

```
cd "$(pwd -P && echo /.)"
```

This changes to what is already the current directory, so it doesn't effectively change the shell process's current directory, but it changes the path that the shell has tracked for the current directory, making it symlink-less.

¹  <sub>This is how the `getcwd` call traditionally operates. Some kernels do keep track of the current directory, but don't track symbolic links, for backward compatibility if for no other reason (but also because of the subtle edge cases with symbolic links).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

It is because `cp` isn't playing the same link game your shell is. Your shell is tracking the links to the current working directory as an indirection to the current working directory, but the kernel doesn't want any of that nonsense when the shell goes to call up `cp` - rather the kernel will make the `cp`'s current working directory a fully qualified absolute path - and so its `.` links and your shell's `.` links are not the same `.`.

You can ensure an absolute path to the current working directory as easily as `cd -P .` and the same will work for any other directory like `cd -P -- /any/other/directory`. You can *at least* use `pwd` to print the absolute path to `.` like `pwd -P`, and in many shells it will alter `$PWD` to the absolute path as well *(in the same way `cd -P .` does)*.

For example:

```sh
cd /tmp
mkdir -p parent child
cd parent
ln -s ../child child
touch ./child/somefile
cd -L child                  ###the default
printf %s\\n "$PWD"/*
cd -P .
printf %s\\n "$PWD"/*
```

#### OUTPUT

```
/tmp/parent/child/somefile
/tmp/child/somefile
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, actually my real problem was with java directory search path, the java program that I was trying to run fetches files from the parent folder and the codes are all in the child (which is a symlink) folder, and this kind of ambiguity is messing up the execution. I thought there should be some way to make a symlink that will respect relative path, but looks like it's not.