# How do I copy files across/outside symbolic links? (dest)

Tags: symlink, cp, directory-structure

Suppose I have a file system like this:

`/home/me/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/file1`

Then in `/home/me/dir1`, I create a symbolic link:

```
$ cd /home/me/dir1
$ ln -s /home/me/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6 linkdir6
```

I am trying to copy file1 to my home directory (this is my simplified example, it's more complicated than this - "/home/me/" is actually a much more complicated directory structure, so "~/" is not a solution).

```
$ cd linkdir6
$ cp file1 ../
$ cd ..
$ ls
dir2 linkdir6
```

I don't see file1.  Searching for it, I find it in `/home/me/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file1`

It seemed `cp` didn't realize it was inside a symbolic directory.

How do I `cp` **out of** a symbolic folder?

Or, how do I make `cp` understand that `../` should be dereferenced (where *dest* in the man page is deferenced)?

Am I missing something?  Is this even possible?

Thanks!

(final note - the actual use case is in a deep directory structure, inside one symlink directory, trying to copy a file ../another-symlink-directory/ without typing complete paths - that's one of the points of symbolic links as far as I'm concerned)

Comment: So, do you expect `file1` in `/home/me/dir1`?

Comment: I _want_ it there, anyway.  I tried so many things, I _expect_ it to not work ;)

Comment: ok, see my answer

Answer (score 3):

You have actually followed the link with the `cd linkdir6`. You are really in that directory, so ../ is one level up from there, in dir5.

Safest way with cp is to be in the target directory. Then use the link to get to the source file.

```
cd ~/me/dir1  #.. Target
cp linkdir6/file1 .
```

Personally, I prefer the -t (target) option in cp.

```
cp -t ~/me/dir1 dir1/linkdir6/file1
```

Comment: Why do you prefer the -t option?

Comment: Also, that's an obvious and straightforward way around the problem!

Comment: @PeterKay (a) cp has an ambiguity: if you intend to cp two files to a directory like cp a b dir, and you forget to type dir, it will copy a over b. I prefer to nail the directory first, while I think about multiple filenames. (b) If you use cp with xargs, it appends multiple filenames, and there is no way to put the dirname last. -t lets you put the dir first as xargs cp -t dir. Same for mv.

Comment: @PeterKay Also, I prefer to stay in my working directory as much as possible. So when I copy stuff out, I can cp -t "${TGT}" and append short local filenames with paste. I'm prone to typos, so I use anything that minimises the risk.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cp file1 "$(cd .. && pwd -P)"
```

See [this
answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191092/72304).

Comment: Oi, that's fairly clunky as syntax, but it does exactly what I wanted - thank you!

Also, the answer you linked helped explain what was going on very well!

Comment: Shouldn't this question simply have been closed as a duplicate of that? They're essentially the same except for the direction of copying.

Comment: Yes, it should be, I voted to close it.

Comment: In some ways it's a duplicate, but the answer given above by Paul_Pedant - while not strictly speaking correct - is going to be a lot more useful to me than the more correct answer (in many cases).

The other (near-duplicate) is much more useful for my understanding of the situation and scripting.

So, I'm not sure I'd want to mark it as a duplicate, but maybe that's appropriate?  I'm not sure :/