# Why does cd-ing to // set PWD to //, but more slashes just gives /?

Tags: linux, filesystems, posix

On my ubuntu box I accidentally just did `cd //` and noticed that my current path changed to `//`. `ls` showed the contents of my root directory.

When I try `cd ///` (or any other number of slashes) I'm just taken directly to the root.

I'm sure this isn't something I need to worry about in any way during every day life but I was wondering if there was some interesting curiosity about why it behaves this way.

Comment: Ah ha – thanks @Brian! I did try to search for it, but it's not the most searchable kind of question (granted, you didn't seem to have any problem finding it).

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and.

Comment: @dhag This is actually more like the one I linked. The asker is talking about how his shell normalizes paths starting with multiple slashes.

Comment: Also (somewhat) related: [Strange difference between pwd and /bin/pwd](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145479/80216).

Answer (score -1):

`cd /` means change directory to root. The amount of slashes does not make a difference.

(source): http://www.linfo.org/cd.html

Comment: If you think a question is in the wrong place, just flag it for migration.

Comment: (1) Your source doesn’t support your answer; it says what `cd /` means (which we ***all*** already know) but doesn’t say anything about `cd //` or multiple slashes.  (2) Something it *does* say is “When used without specifying any directory name, cd returns the user to the previous current directory.” — which, of course, is wrong — so it’s not a very trustworthy source.