# Does cd . have use?

Tags: cd-command

One of the tutorials I've been following briefly stated that `cd .` has no use.  When trying to replicate issue shown by OP in [Symbolic link recursion - what makes it “reset”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79571/85039), I also tried `cd .`, which showed the same effect OP described (growing `$PWD` variable), which can be countered with `cd -P`.

This makes me wonder, is there any case where one does in fact would want to use `cd .`  ?

Comment: I have a custom .zshrc that runs various checks on the directory when switching directory, for example one of the check is to automatically activate/deactivate a matching virtualenv when moving directories. Occasionally, I might start a new shell or whatever, and those checks don't run, and I usually use `cd .` to trigger those checks because it's short and simple. Though I think you intended the question to be for a vanilla environment.

Comment: @LieRyan No, I didn't really intend it to be restricted to vanilla environment only. The only concert here is whether or not `cd .`  is useful, and whether there's more to it than just face-value navigation to same directory. You can convert your comment into an answer, as it may be useful to others.

Comment: Besides the (obvious) effect on `$PWD`, `cd .` also changes `$OLDPWD` to the current directory.  I have (currently) no idea why this might be useful, but for the sake of completeness…

Comment: I don't think I've ever needed `cd .`, though seeing the answers below, I might in the future, but I have on occasion used `pushd .` when I wanted to be able to `popd` back to this directory later. e.g. when running a build script that does `configure`, `cd output...` and `make`, and when it's done I'll want to go back to the original directory. Rather than maintaining my own copy of the buildscript that's different than what everyone else expects, I just run it as `pushd .; ./BuildScriptName.sh; popd`, and this also gives me the freedom to not `popd` sometimes, and then `popd` later instead.

Comment: Not to mention of course that '.' and '..' are not implemented in the cd command itself, so no-one set out to make that specific feature, it's just a combination of things that serves no real purpose.

Comment: `cd` is a shell built-in command. What shell do you ask about?

Comment: @enkryptor   It is a built-in in most shells, but on some systems it's also available as `/bin/cd` and IIRC is required by POSIX. There's no specific restriction to which shell this question applies, and I as shown in linked question and some of the already existing answers - behavior of `cd .` can vary by shell, so addressing multiple cases is necessary.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy: Re: "on some systems it's also available as `/bin/cd`": Wait, how does that work? Are there Unixlike systems where an executable program is allowed to mess with the parent process's execution environment?

Comment: @ruakh  Nope, external programs should not affect shell execution environment. It's mostly for POSIX compliance which requires some of the utilities to exist outside of the shell, and evaluating exit status of external commands. You can read about the purpose of `/bin/cd` here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058/85039

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy: Fascinating; thanks for the link!

Comment: @ruakh  It's worth noting, though, that  in original Unix there was external `chdir` that did affect shell's execution environment, according to Dennis Ritchie's article [The Evolution of the Unix Time-sharing System*](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/hist.html). According to it, when they realized that it stopped working with newly added `fork()` syscall, they  decided to make it a shell built-in, or so I understand.  Eventually `chdir` was dropped, apparently in Version 7 ([source](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/))

Comment: Esoteric perhaps, but I use the fish shell with the git branch plugin. If I checkout a new branch in a different terminal window, then I run `cd .` to cause the plugin to display the correct branch.

Comment: I use `cd -P .` almost every day, does that count? When you've cd'ed somewhere through symlinks, that can be very useful to figure out where you really are. Is that relevant or are you only asking about `cd .` with no flags?

Answer (score 156):

I think this is overthinking the problem. `cd .` may not be something that one would manually run in the usual course of things, but it definitely is something that can come up in programmatic execution (think of any situation where you might `cd` to the directory containing a file, whose path is supplied by the user). Therefore, it doesn't have to have some specific use: as long as it fulfills the usual semantics of `cd <some-path>`, it is useful.

Comment: Agreed,  `.` should be treated as a valid path specified by `cd` syntax just fine.

Comment: You can add the following example: Loops like while `IFS= read Dir; do cd "$Dir"; do_something; done < <(find . -type d)`. During its course, find produces `.` as path, so that the command `cd "$Dir"` expands to `cd .`. So, in scripts, it is perfectly useful.

Comment: @rexkogitans your illustration is clear but the code would fail on its second iteration. You would need to put the `cd` and subsequent code in a subshell so that the relative directory path remained relative to the starting point rather than to the previous iteration.

Comment: @roaima Feel free to add `cd -` to `do_something`

Comment: For example, a script actually runs `cd ${path_to_directory}`, but at some point it turns out the directory is the current directory, and `path_to_directory = .` so you would need `cd .` to work just in case.

Comment: In other words, its utility is in the fact that it makes extra code (`if` checks and `else` clauses, any kind of special casing) unnecessary.

Comment: So it's useful in the sense that x+0 or x*1 are useful - the specific operation isn't useful per se, but it means that you can handle 0 and 1 the same as any other value, without having to treat them as a special case.

Comment: @user32929 that's kinda the opposite. The [axioms defining operations like addition or multiplication](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldAxioms.html) typically include 0 and 1 within them, since those are the respective identities. Here, though, it just follows from the definition of `.` in paths and what `cd` is supposed to do with paths.

Answer (score 127):

The path of the directory could have changed since the last command was executed, and without `cd .` the bash and ksh93 shells will rely on the logical working directory described in the post linked in the question, so calling `cd .` which makes the shell issue the `getcwd()` syscall will ensure your current path is still valid.

Steps to reproduce in bash:

1. In a terminal tab issue `mkdir ./dir_no_1; cd ./dir_no_1`
2. In a different terminal tab issue `mv dir_no_1 dir_no_2`
3. In the first terminal tab issue `echo $PWD` and `pwd`. Notice that the directory has been externally renamed; the shell's environment has not been updated.
4. Issue `cd .; pwd; echo $PWD`. Notice the value has been updated.

ksh93, however, does not update the environment information, so `cd .` in ksh93 may in fact be useless.   In `/bin/dash` on Ubuntu and other Debian-based systems, `cd .` returns `dash: 3: cd: can't cd to .` error, however `cd -P .` works (unlike in ksh93).

Comment: Good to know: I'll add that to my list of useless informations. ^^)

Comment: @jayooin Glad I could contribute to the list ;)

Comment: I think you can do `mv ../dir_no_1 ../dir_no_2` in the **same** terminal/bash.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Confirmed, works :)

Comment: It's also possible that `pwd` might be a shell builtin that bypasses the syscall to `getcwd()` and is basically an alias for `echo $PWD` - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145479/strange-difference-between-pwd-and-bin-pwd. I can't test that there's a difference since my shells use the "real" `pwd`, but you might want to explicitly specify `/bin/pwd` just in case. Shells sure are fun, eh?

Comment: @ymbirtt  In most shells, `pwd` is in fact a built in, however invoking `/bin/pwd` has no effect on shell's environment - external utilities  in general don't affect the shell environment.  The reason why `/bin/cd` and `/bin/pwd` exist is for POSIX conformance, among other things. There's a [good discussion about external cd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058/85039) some of which probably applies to `/bin/pwd` as well

Comment: Thank you for saving me writing an answer...

Comment: Common reason this happens to me:  I have a tmux session open from a place where I run various administrative commands, but the deployment process for new code checks out the code in a temporary location and then moves it over so as to make the process atomic.  `cd .` then ensures that I'm in the correct most-recent deployed version of the code.

Answer (score 55):

Another use case of `cd .` would be when the directory you currently are in has been deleted and then made again. Consider trying the following -

1. Create a directory `temp`
2. `cd temp` and then do an `ls`
3. Open another terminal and delete and then recreate that directory `temp`
4. Back from the first terminal, try doing an ls. This would result in an error - `ls: cannot open directory .: Stale file handle`
5. `cd .` and then doing an ls works fine

Comment: This doesn't always work. In dash, for example, you'll get: `cd: can't cd to .` Now that I look at it, this is already mentioned in Sergiy's answer (moving, deleting/recreating - essentially the same: the directory you're in is no longer what was in the original path)

Comment: I use this a lot testing remote deploys. The directory I'm in will be deleted then recreated by some automation and I'll need to issue `cd .` to move to the new directory with the same name.

Comment: I use `cd .` all the time when I have a shell whose current working directory was mounted with sshfs but the ssh session has been closed and reopened.

Comment: In such a case I do "cd $PWD". Other variants might work, but this one clearly expresses the intent: extract what is supposed to be my current path (i.e. read content of `PWD` environment variable), then walk the filesystem hierarchy from the root, down to a directory that happens to be reachable via that path, whether it is actually the same directory or not. This fits exactly the use case in this answer.

Comment: @roaima it can definitely occur outside of NFS.  For instance, while working with Git.  (I [wrote an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496374/135943) to that effect.)

Comment: @Wildcard, ah. It's dependent on the shell being used. For example `bash` translates `cd .` to `cd "$PWD"` but not every shell does this.

Comment: I'm really surprised, shocked even,  that `cd .` works when the directory has been unlinked and a new, different directory is created at the same file-system path. The current working directory has been unlinked and presumably as part of that, it no longer has a `.` or `..` entry, and even if it did, the `.` entry should continue to point to itself.   It looks like the shell or the kernel is executing the cd command based on what the directory path name was rather than simply accessing the `.` entry.  Can anyone confirm that behaviour?

Comment: @AdrianPronk See roaima's comment above.

Comment: I just did that, and after deleting the directory in the other terminal, a call of `stat .` in the first terminal gave me the same inode as before, so the inode seems to still exist immediately after the removal. Also `ls -la` does not give an error for me, but says `total 0`.

Answer (score 36):

You can clear `$OLDPWD` with a quick `cd .`, if there should be a case where you don't want it to point anywhere "interesting". It'll also affect `cd -`.

Answer (score 16):

Programmatically it's useful as a no-op. Consider a path provided from external input.

```
read -p "Path to file: " p
dirn=$(dirname "$p")
file=$(basename "$p")
echo "dirn=$dirn, file=$file"
cd "$dirn"
ls -ld "$file"
```

With a path such as "fred.txt" the directory will become `.`, leading to `cd .`

Comment: It's useful that it doesn't throw an error if you're already in the directory that you're navigating to, but I wouldn't say that it is useful as a no-op.

Comment: @CaptainMan not throwing an error if you're already in the directory is (effectively) a no-op. The `dirname` command generates `.` where necessary to avoid breaking code that expects to be able to split a path.

Answer (score 14):

This is common if you had to work with a bad USB cable. After a device get disconnected and connected again, and automounted to the same directory, you have to use `cd .` to get it work again.

Comment: Won't that depend upon what sort of device, how it's being accessed, its filesystem, the OS, &c?

Comment: OS, maybe. It's unlikely the filesystem is relevant, as long as the kernel can find its way unmounting it while it is being used. In any case, the command has its use in the exactly right situation.

Answer (score 11):

Note that "." *is* the proper way to specify the name of the file that is open as the current working directory of any process (including a shell process of course), and "." is always a valid name of a file in any and all directories, including the current working directory.  The name `.` may not be a valid name for a file for a given instance of a process if, say, the underlying current working directory has been removed (or gone "bad", e.g. a stale NFS handle), but it is a valid name of a file that is guaranteed to exist in every valid directory.

So `.` **must** be a valid argument for any command that accepts the name of a directory, and thus in the standard shell `cd .` must be a valid command.

Whether `cd .` is useful or not depends on the shell implementation.  As mentioned it can be useful if the shell resets its internal idea of the full pathname of the current working directory after calling the underlying `chdir` system call, say for example if the underlying directory (or some parent of it) has been renamed.

At least some shells I know (`/bin/sh` on FreeBSD and NetBSD) will convert `cd ""` into `cd .`, which can arguably be described a feature to support programmatic use in a shell script where a variable might be used as a parameter (i.e. converting an empty variable substitution into a "do nothing" result), though the FreeBSD commit history says the change was directly due to adding POSIX support to prevent a failure from `chdir("")`, which POSIX mandates must fail.

Some other shells will replace the `.` with whatever they have stored as the fully qualified pathname to their current working directory, and thus for them this may allow for the behaviour mentioned in [Sahil Agarwal's answer](/a/495912).

Answer (score 4):

I used this command just today when I rebased the branch I was working on in Git, from within a directory which had first been created on that same branch.  The rebase went fine but afterwards, `git status` threw an error.  After `cd .` everything was normal.

(I was working in MobaXterm on Windows, incidentally.  Just in case you're trying to reproduce this.  It may not happen on other systems.)

---

I also have used this command in directories that are refreshed by an automated process that moves aside the old directory and replaces it with a new one (so it is as close to atomic as possible).  Not a common situation but `cd .` is exactly what's needed.

---

After reading this excellent answer from Stephane Chazelas:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79621/135943

I now understand that my use cases above only work because I am using `bash`, in which `cd .` is equivalent to `cd "$PWD"`.  I highly recommend reading the linked answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use `cd .` to rerun the stuff I've overloaded `cd` with via a `bash` function.

From my `~/.bashrc`:

```
# from the "xttitle(1)" man page - put info in window title
update_title()
{
    [[ $TERM = xterm ]] || [[ $TERM = xterm-color ]]  && xttitle "[$$] ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:$PWD"
}

cd()
{
    [[ -z "$*" ]] && builtin cd $HOME
    [[ -n "$*" ]] && builtin cd "$*"
    update_title
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This has already been suggested by [Sahil](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495912/67833) previously.

This is useful if you are inside a folder that got deleted and recreated by another process. For example, assuming the two terminal sessions `$1` and `$2`:

```
$1 mkdir d
$1 cd d
$1 touch f

$2 rm -rf /path/to/d # delete the folder where $1 is in ...
$2 mkdir /path/to/d # ... and recreate it

$1 touch g # cannot create file g because current dir doesn't exist anymore
touch: cannot touch ‘g’: Stale file handle
$1 cd . # go to the newly created dir (same path)
$1 touch g # works fine now
```

I am not sure whether where exactly (OS, SHELL, ...?) the root cause of this behavior is.

Comment: This has already been mentioned by other answers.