# what is the purpose of "cd ." command?

Tags: bash, cd-command

We know that the `cd` command is used to change directories. For example

```
 cd dirname
```

valid dirnames include `.` and `..` as well. The purpose of `cd ..` is clear. From the manpage:

> A null directory name in CDPATH is the
>   same as the current directory,  i.e., ''.''.

But then what is the purpose of `cd .`?

Comment: See also [Does cd . have use?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/495899/315749)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The effect of `cd .` is to update the shell with information about what the current working directory is. This could be useful in circumstances when the (pathname of the) current directory changes by other means than through `cd`.

```
$ pwd
/tmp/shell-bash.OoVntBAM
$ mkdir dir
$ cd dir
$ pwd
/tmp/shell-bash.OoVntBAM/dir
```

So, we're currently some place under `/tmp`, in a directory called `dir`.  Let's rename the directory we're currently in.

```
$ mv ../dir ../new-dir
```

So, where are we now?

```
$ pwd
/tmp/shell-bash.OoVntBAM/dir
```

Really? Why, that's odd.  Let's make sure the shell knows were we are.

```
$ cd .
$ pwd
/tmp/shell-bash.OoVntBAM/new-dir
```

---

In a script, `cd .` could possibly be used to test whether the user still as access to the current directory:

```sh
if ! cd . 2>/dev/null; then
    echo lost access to cwd >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Or, the other way around, to *verify* that the current directory is no longer accessible after some sort of operation to revoke access for the current user.

Reasons for loosing access to the current directory includes having the directory removed, or someone removing one's execute permissions on it.

---

Another example is using `cd .`, but with the `-P` option, i.e. `cd -P .`.  This would put you in the "physical" directory if the current directory was otherwise accessed through a symbolic link:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/shell-bash.OoVntBAM
$ mkdir dir
$ ln -s dir link-dir
$ ls -l
total 2
drwxr-xr-x  3 kk  wheel  512 May  8 00:48 dir
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kk  wheel    3 May  8 00:46 link-dir -> dir
```

So now we have a directory, `dir`, and a symbolic link to that directory. Let's enter the directory through the symbolic link:

```
$ cd link-dir
$ pwd
/tmp/shell-bash.OoVntBAM/link-dir
```

Then...

```
$ cd -P .
$ pwd
/tmp/shell-bash.OoVntBAM/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct quote for `cd ..` should be:

> `..' is processed by removing the immediately previous pathname component
>       back to a slash or the beginning of DIR.

And, yes, `cd .` shouldn't change the current directory, and, yes it doesn't.
But the name of the present directory might have changed:

```
$ mkdir thisdir
$ cd thisdir
$ cd .
$ pwd
/home/isaac/thisdir
$ mv ../thisdir ../xxxx
$ cd .
$ pwd
/home/isaac/xxxx
```

Or the present directory contains a symlink or its physical directory name has changed.

```
$ cd ~/ttt
$ pwd
/home/isaac/ttt
$ cd -P .
$ pwd
/home/isaac/me/init/basicdirs.d/ttt
```

So, `cd .` is used as any other `cd DIR`, to change the `pwd` to `DIR`. It may appear to be the same directory, but, even being the same directory, DIR might have a different name or path.