# Why can I cd to // but not /// or //// or ///// or …

Tags: directory, pwd

When I change directory to `//`, it seems to put me in a special directory that is very similar to but slightly different to `/`. However, trying to add any further slashes (`///`) simply drops me in `/`.

```
$ cd /    ;pwd
/
$ cd //   ;pwd
//
$ cd ///  ;pwd
/
$ cd //// ;pwd
/
```

It seems that `//` is somehow special, even though it has the same directories and everything, it's still a different string returned by `pwd`. Why is this? Why can my working directory be `//` but not `///`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`//` is a special case, covered in the [POSIX definition of the word "Pathname"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_267):

> Multiple successive `<slash>` characters are considered to be the same as one `<slash>`, except for the case of exactly two leading `<slash>` characters.

On most systems `//` is the same as `/`, but it is allowed to be different according to POSIX.

Further reading:

- [On what systems is //foo/bar different from /foo/bar?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256497/135943)
- [How does Linux handle multiple consecutive path separators (/home////username///file)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1910/135943)
- [unix, difference between path starting with '/' and '//'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12283/135943)

(I think the first of these links is the best.)

Comment: I have been using Unix/SunOS/Linux/etc for 20+ years, and yet... TIL. "If a pathname begins with two successive <slash> characters, the first component following the leading <slash> characters may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading <slash> characters shall be treated as a single <slash> character."