# What's the difference between the pile paths '/' and '//'?

Tags: bash, filesystems, filenames, root-filesystem

I noticed in Ubuntu that the following commands go to seemingly different locations in the file system, but the locations have the same files:

```
cd /
cd //
```

ls-ing from both locations produces the same result:

```
vm@virtual-machine://$ ls
bin    dev   initrd.img      lib64       mnt   root  snap      sys  var
boot   etc   initrd.img.old  lost+found  opt   run   srv       tmp  vmlinuz
cdrom  home  lib             media       proc  sbin  swapfile  usr
```

Is there a distinction in the behaviors in these to seemingly different, yet the same file paths?

Note: '`cd ///`' is not a valid file path, but '`//usr/`' and '`//bin/`' are valid paths.
Note-2: So running cd .. in in each points to themselves, so `// -> cd .. -> //` and `/ -> cd .. -> /`

Comment: This answers your question: [unix, difference between path starting with '/' and '//'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and)

Comment: @ThomasDickey Sort of! In the answer, the user says "but ///foo is equivalent to /foo", but you can see in my note that /// is not a valid file path.    Why is this? is the answer wrong, or are there special cases?

Comment: Also; in this answer, the user mentions behavior relating to a 'implementation-defined manner'. what sort of behaviors can I expect?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12284/459032

Comment: `///` is a valid path (which is equivalent to `/`) and `cd ///` is a valid command. What do you mean by “'cd ///' is not a valid file path”?

Comment: @tuskiomi: "implementation-defined" is a standard formulation in specifications (it features heavily in C and C++ for example) and means exactly what it sounds like: the behavior is defined by the implementation and the standard does not say anything about what that behavior may be. So, Linux could launch a nuclear missile when you `cd //` whereas macOS could brick your computer, FreeBSD could do nothing at all, NetBSD could treat it as `/`, Solaris could use it for file sharing, HP-UX could use it for accessing windows on the desktop, …

Comment: @JörgWMittag so it's technical-speak for 'do anything' or 'no wrong answers'?

Comment: @tuskiomi: No, you are thinking of "undefined behavior". "Implementation-defined behavior" *is* well-defined and predictable, it's just defined in the manual of the implementation rather than the standard. And thus different on different implementations, but consistent on one implementation. Undefined behavior is *not* required to be consistent even on the same implementation, and in fact, implementations take advantage of that: when a user invokes undefined behavior, the implementation will often assume that behavior to be whatever is fastest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the POSIX specification, paths that begin with *exactly two slashes* have implementation-defined semantics.

Multiple slashes in a path are collapsed to one slash, *except* for the case where there is *exactly two* slashes at *exactly the beginning* of the path.

So, `/foo`, `///foo`, `////foo`, and `///////////////////foo` are guaranteed to be the same path, `/foo/bar`, `/foo//bar`, `/foo///bar`, and so on are guaranteed to be the same path, but `/foo` and `//foo` are *not* guaranteed to be the same path, and neither are `//foo` and `///foo` – any implementation can define the semantics as they wish. They *could* choose to define `//foo` to mean the same thing as `/foo` and `///foo`, but they don't *have to*.

The intention is that operating systems can use paths beginning with `//` to implement semantics that are different from POSIX file system semantics.

For example, a hypothetical hybrid of Windows and Unix could use `//` for Windows filesystem semantics. Cygwin actually uses `//` for network paths, similar to how Windows uses `\\`.

In Cygwin, for example, `cd //; ls` would list all SMB fileserver on the local network, not the root directory!

Comment: Is cygwin the only bash implementation that has special implementation for double-slashes? in my example, I'm using Ubuntu, which doesn't seem to have any special behavior.