# Trailing slashes on symbolic links to directories

Tags: directory, filenames, symlink, coreutils

I'm trying to emulate the process of path resolution (see man page path_resolution) in unix-like systems.

My OS is Linux with GNU coreutils 8.7.

In order to clarify the meaning of extra trailing '/' in resolution,
I did following things in a shell:

```
mkdir this_is_dir
ln -s this_is_dir this_is_link
rm this_is_link
```

Everything was fine, because this_is_link is a symlink, and I just removed it away.
But while trying:

```
mkdir this_is_dir
ln -s this_is_dir this_is_link
rm this_is_link/
```

It echoed `rm: cannot remove 'this_is_link/': Is a directory`

Well, the trailing '/' caused following of symlink, I thought.
So, I tried another command: `rmdir this_is_link/`

And a funny result came out: `rmdir: failed to remove 'this_is_link/': Not a directory`

Not what I expected. So I asked my friend to confirm if the same result could be obtained on his system. He had a lower version of coreutils than I had. And the result was amazing, **no matter `rm` or `rmdir 'this_is_link/'`, the same error `Not a directory` occurs**.

And another friend just tried it out on his Mac OS, the result is: **`rm` => 'Is a directory', `rmdir` => the directory is successfully deleted, the link remained**.

Are there any spec about the **exact** behavior of path resolution?

Comment: See also [How linux handles multiple path separators (/home////username///file)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [POSIX/Single Unix specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) specifies that a pathname with a trailing slash must refer to a directory (see [base definitions §4.11 pathname resolution](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11)). `foo/` is in fact defined as equivalent to `foo/.` (for path resolution purposes, not when manipulating file names; `basename` and `dirname` ignore trailing slashes). Most implementations respect this, but there are a few exceptions.

This explains the behavior of `rm this_is_link/`: it's equivalent to `rm this_is_link/.`, where the argument is clearly a directory.

`rmdir this_is_link/` should similarly refer to the directory. That it doesn't on your machine is a bug in GNU coreutils. OSX is behaving correctly here.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, thanks guy!

Comment: if `path/` was equivalent to `path/.`, then `rmdir` would have to fail too, because the `rmdir` utility is supposed to "perform actions equivalent to the `rmdir()` function", and the `rmdir()` function should fail with EINVAL when "The path argument contains a last component that is dot". (The quotes are from the POSIX). Or that should not apply when the trailing `/.` is, like, imaginary? That may be. Anyways, the behaviour of the `rmdir` utility from GNU coreutils correctly reflects that of the `rmdir()` function of the system it runs on, and this answer is wrong.

Comment: @user414777 IIRC what you explain was reported as a defect on the POSIX specification and the semantics of a trailing slash have been modified to make this case work "intuitively".

Comment: Even if that's a bug in Linux, it's still not bug in GNU coreutils, as you claim. GNU's `rmdir` will work as you expected on OSX.

Comment: Coreutils > 8.32 will have more helpful error messages in this regard:
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2021-02/msg00009.html

Specifically `rmdir: failed to remove 'this_is_link/': Symbolic link not followed`

Answer (score -1):

My take:

- ''rm link/'' fails because rm looks at the last char, sees it's a slash, gives the (not really correct) diagnostic you saw;
- ''rmdir link/'' fails alright: link is not a directory, it is a symlink
- ''rm link'' will correctly succeed

Incidentally, path resolution has very little to do with this, it just appears to be ''rm'' cutting a corner rather than (correctly) invoking "stat" on an argument (which is what rmdir is doing).

Cheers.

Comment: Actually, the converse seems to be true: `rm` does call stat (well, newfstatat, actually, with the `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW` option) and refuses to proceed any further, whereas rmdir actually calls rmdir(2), but gets `ENOTDIR`.

Comment: @AnsgarEsztermann `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW` will prevent it from following the symlink, so rm should delete the link itself instead of printing "Not a directory" which does not match the circumstance.

Comment: From a brief check with stat(1), the trailing slash will override the option. The output of `stat` and `stat -L` differ only if the argument is given without a trailing slash.

Comment: @AnsgarEsztermann Oh, I see...Thx. How about the different effects on different evironment? Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "environment"? Different OSs/OS versions? Older `rm` (tried with coreutils 6.12) does not call newfstatat, but tries unlinkat immediately. Other OSs may have different implementations of syscalls, so their behaviour may differ even more.

Comment: @AnsgarEsztermann Gotcha. Thx!

Comment: It's the opposite: on ymfoi's machine, `rm` is behaving correctly and `rmdir` isn't. The trailing `/` should force them to treat their argument as a directory, per the POSIX standard. [See my answer for references](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29769/puzzled-by-path-resolution-in-unix-like-systems/29836#29836).

Comment: <gripe>So if my comment was partly correct why was it (with no explanation BTW) downvoted?</gripe>