# How come rm symlink/ and rmdir simlink/ report symlink/ as both a directory and not a directory?

Tags: linux, symlink

I have `testlink -> testtarget//` and `rm` and `rmdir` report the following:

```
$ rm testlink/
rm: cannot remove 'testlink/': Is a directory
$ rmdir testlink/
rmdir: failed to remove 'testlink/': Not a directory
```

Of course I can remove the symlink with `rm testlink`, but why does Linux report that the symlink is both a directory and not a directory?

Comment: Is `testtarget` a directory?

Comment: Anyway, this looks like a bug in GNU coreutils https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29836/72304

Comment: Or maybe even in Linux https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2014-11/msg00028.html

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes, `testtarget` is a directory.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk It seems that this behavior of Linux is intentional, rather than a bug. Anyways, it's probably too late to change, and having `rmdir src/` remove the directory that `src` points to -- turning `src` it into a dangling symlink *without removing it* (as it actually happens on BSD), doesn't feel like something that useful, either.