# In a bash shell how do I delete the last "/" of a path?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Say for example I have a path like

```
path_1=/this/is/a/path/with/slash/
```

How do I get the following:

```
/this/is/a/path/with/slash
```

so the path without the last "/"

Comment: Assuming the original path is valid (`…/slash/` leads to a directory), if you want to postpend a `component` and you're not sure if `$path_1` ends with `/`, don't bother and just postpend `/component`: `…/slash//component` [will work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/108618) like `…/slash/component`. There's at least one situation when the trailing slash matters though: if `slash` is a symlink to a directory then `…/slash/` [means the directory, certainly not the symlink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29836/108618), while `…/slash` may mean the symlink. Then your question is useful.

Comment: Isn't his a duplicate? I.e.: I cannot believe this hadn't be asked and answered several hundred times.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47592882/6607497 for example.

Comment: that answer is barely understandable. The replies to this question are much better.

Answer (score 29):

All POSIX shells have (c.f. `man bash`) "Parameter Expansion: Remove matching suffix pattern". So, use

```bsh
$ echo "${path_1%/}"
/this/is/a/path/with/slash
```

If the variable's value does *not* end in a slash, then the value would be outputted without modification.

Comment: This has one possible problem: if the path is just "/" (i.e. the filesystem root), you *don't* want to remove the `/` because it'll turn into the empty string, which means something entirely different.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `realpath`

```
DIR=/tmp/foo///
echo "$(realpath -s "$DIR")"
# output: /tmp/foo
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of removing the slash is

```
 $ echo "$(dirname -- "$path")/$(basename -- "$path")"
```

We just combined the two common shell commands `dirname` and `basename`.

Comment: You need to quote the expansion of `$path` and also the command substitution itself to avoid the issues mentioned in [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary). (See also [What's the right way to quote $(command $arg)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443989/whats-the-right-way-to-quote-command-arg/443990#443990)). Also if the filename can start with a dash, `--` is needed so that it's not taken as a bunch of options. Of course this will also rewrite paths like `foo/` into `./foo`.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you use `path` as the variable's name. In the `bash` shell, it doesn't matter, but the `path` array variable in the `zsh` shell is tied to the `PATH` variable and will contain the elements of the `PATH` variable's `:`-delimited values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sed in a simple way like this:

```
$ echo $path_1|sed 's-/$--'
/this/is/a/path/with/slash
```

Explanation:

- s: Substitute. The first - marks the end of the command.
- /$: Search pattern. The $ means look at the end of the line.
- There is nothing between the second and third -, meaning, "replace the ending / with nothing".
- You can use any character instead of `-` the most common is `/`, but since we are looking for the / itself, it is easier to use some other character. If one really wants to use /, then it would need to be escaped like so:

`$ echo $path_1|sed 's/\/$//'`

Answer (score 1):

There are several options. I usually canonicalise the path. When you canonicalise a path, you get the base path.

For example, if the path is a link to a folder, the canonical form will get the actual path. It will also remove all double-slashes, which although unusual, are allowed in Unix and Linux.

Suppose `~/lf` is a link to `~/.hidden/food/limes/`.

```
PATHNAME=~/lf//price/
CANONICAL_PATH="$( realpath --canonicalize-existing "${PATHNAME}" )"
echo "${CANONICAL_PATH}"
```

The result would be `/home/kamil/.hidden/food/limes/price`

This also works for files, block devices, etc., although of course they don't have a trailing slash. For example, on my system:

```
PATHNAME=/dev/disk/by-partlabel/Boot
CANONICAL_PATH="$( realpath --canonicalize-existing "${PATHNAME}" )"
echo "${CANONICAL_PATH}"
```

The result is `/dev/nvme0n1p2`

If you aren't sure that the path exists, you need to add some error-checking.

```
PATHNAME=~/lf//price/
CANONICAL_PATH="$( realpath --canonicalize-existing "${PATHNAME}" 2>/dev/null )"
if [[ -z ${CANONICAL_PATH} ]]
then
    echo "Path doesn't exist: ${PATHNAME}" >&2
else
   echo "Canonical path is ${CANONICAL_PATH}"
fi
```