# Does ~ always equal $HOME

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, home

I know this has probably been asked before, but I couldn't find it with Google.

Given

- Linux Kernel
- No configurations that change $HOME
- bash

Will `~ == $HOME` be true?

Comment: I believe so, but this is not a Linux-specific issue. Rather, I believe `~` will be equivalent to `$HOME` in any POSIX environment; but I could be wrong.

Comment: Despite the answers below… not always. Compare `echo "~"` and `echo "$HOME"`.

Comment: @Sparhawk Wait, so 1+1 *isn't* 2? It's a conspiracy! The government is hiding something from us! :P

Comment: @Sparhawk, you'll notice the OP actually did not quote either the `~` or `$HOME`. :P

Comment: @HalosGhost Ah, good point. (Also, I later noticed that Michael Homer's [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146672/18887) mentions "a single unquoted `~`".) Anyway, something to keep in mind for the casual reader, like myself.

Comment: Depends. Try. if [[ ~ == $HOME ]]; then echo yes; fi

Comment: Perhaps the question should add the stipulation:  _‘In such contexts where **tilde expansion** will occur,’_

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What's important to understand is that `~` expansion is a feature of the shell (of some shells), it's not a magic character than means your home directory wherever it's used.

It is expanded (by the shell, which is an application used to interpret command lines), like `$var` is expanded to its value under some conditions when used in a shell command line before the command is executed.

That feature first appeared in the C-shell in the late 1970s (the Bourne shell didn't have it, nor did its predecessor the Thompson shell), was later added to the Korn shell (a newer shell built upon the Bourne shell in the 80s). It was eventually standardized by POSIX and is now available in most shells including non-POSIX ones like `fish`.

Because it's in such widespread use in shells, some non-shell applications also recognise it as meaning the home directory. That's the case of many applications in their configuration files or their *own* command line (`mutt`, `slrn`, `vim`...).

`bash` specifically (which is the shell of the GNU project and widely used in many Linux-based operating systems), when invoked as `sh`, mostly follows the [POSIX rules](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01) about `~` expansion, and in areas not specified by POSIX, behaves mostly like the Korn shell (of which it is a part clone).

While `$var` is expanded in most places (except inside single quotes), `~` expansion, being an afterthought is only expanded in a few specific conditions.

It is expanded when on its own argument in list contexts, in contexts where a string is expected.

Here are a few examples of where it's expanded in `bash`:

- `cmd arg ~ other arg`
- `var=~`
- `var=x:~:x` (required by POSIX, used for variables like `PATH`, `MANPATH`...)
- `for i in ~`
- `[[ ~ = text ]]`
- `[[ text = ~ ]]` (the expansion of `~` being taken as a pattern in AT&T `ksh` but not `bash` since 4.0).
- `case ~ in ~) ...`
- `${var#~}` (though not in some other shells)
- `cmd foo=~` (though not when invoked as `sh`, and only when what's on the left of the `=` is shaped like an unquoted `bash` variable name)
- `cmd ~/x` (required by POSIX obviously)
- `cmd ~:x` (but not `x:~:x` or `x-~-x`)
- `a[~]=foo; echo "${a[~]} $((a[~]))"` (not in some other shells)

Here are a few examples where it's not expanded:

- `echo "~" '~'`
- `echo ~@ ~~` (also note that `~u` is meant to expand to the home directory of user `u`).
- `echo @~`
- `(( HOME == ~ ))`, `$(( var + ~ ))`
- with `extglob`: `case $var in @(~|other))...` (though `case $var in ~|other)` is OK).
- `./configure --prefix=~` (as `--prefix` is not a valid variable name)
- `cmd "foo"=~` (in `bash`, because of the quotes).
- when invoked as `sh`: `export "foo"=~`, `env JAVA_HOME=~ cmd`...

As to what it expands to: `~` alone expands to the content of the `HOME` variable, or when it is not set, to the home directory of the current user in the account database (as an extension since POSIX leaves that behaviour undefined).

It should be noted that in ksh88 and `bash` versions prior to 4.0, tilde expansion underwent globbing (filename generation) in list contexts:

```
$ bash -c 'echo "$HOME"'
/home/***stephane***
$ bash -c 'echo ~'
/home/***stephane*** /home/stephane
$ bash -c 'echo "~"'
~
```

That should not be a problem in usual cases.

Note that because it's expanded, the same warning applies as other forms of expansions.

```
cd ~
```

Doesn't work if `$HOME` starts with `-` or contains `..` components. So, even though it's very unlikely to ever make any difference, strictly speaking, one should write:

```
cd -P -- ~
```

Or even:

```
case ~ in
  (/*) cd -P ~;;
  (*) d=~; cd -P "./$d";;
esac
```

(to cover for values of `$HOME` like `-`, `+2`...) or simply:

```
cd
```

(as `cd` takes you to your home directory without any argument)

Other shells have more advanced `~` expansions. For instance, in `zsh`, we have:

- `~4`, `~-`, `~-2` (with completion) used to expand the directories in your directory stack (the places you've `cd` to before).
- *dynamic named directories*. You can define your own mechanism to decide how `~something` is being expanded.

Answer (score 26):

[In any version of Bash on any system, yes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion). `~` as a term on its own is defined to expand to:

> The value of $HOME

so it will always be the same as whatever `$HOME` is to the current shell. There are several other tilde expansions, such as `~user` for `user`'s home directory, but a single unquoted `~` on its own will always expand to `"$HOME"`.

Note that the *behaviour* of `~` and `$HOME` can be different in some cases: in particular, if `$HOME` contains spaces (or other [IFS](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-IFS) characters), then `$HOME` (unquoted) will expand to multiple words, while `~` is always a single word. `~` expands equivalently to `"$HOME"` (quoted).

In regard to your specific question:

```
[[ $HOME == ~ ]]
```

is always true, because `[[` [suppresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b) word-splitting. `[[ ~ == $HOME ]` may not be if `HOME` has [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) characters in it, but `[[ ~ == "$HOME" ]]` (i.e., quoted `"$HOME"`) is always true. Using it inside single brackets can be a syntax error for values of `HOME` containing spaces or special characters. For any sensible home directory configuration `~` and `"$HOME"` are the same and compare as equal.

---

Stéphane Chazelas has noted a case in the comments where `~` and `$HOME` give different values: if you [`unset HOME`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-unset), then when you use `~` Bash will call [`getpwuid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwuid.html) to read a value out of the password database. This case is excluded by your condition of having no configuration changing `$HOME`, but I'll mention it here for completeness.

Comment: However, `/bin/sh` might not be `bash`. I'm not sure that Posix `sh` specification tells about `~`

Comment: POSIX specifies `~`. `~` was not in the Thomson or Bourne shell (that in their time were available as `/bin/sh`). It's not in `rc` or its derivatives (where it's used for something else)

Comment: You also need to quote `$HOME` in `[[ xx = $HOME ]]` in `ksh` and `bash` as otherwise it's considered as a pattern (so the above would return false for a value of HOME like `/[a]`)

Comment: `[ ~ = $HOME ]` can be false without a syntax error with values of `$HOME` like `/a -a a = a`. Leaving `$HOME` unquoted in that context doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? It's not part of the command language or `sh`'s description, and at least one version of `sh` I have access to doesn't support it (Solaris).

Comment: In a few shells including `bash`, if `HOME` is unset, `~` expands to the home directory of the user from the passwd database. So that's a case where `~` may not expand to the value of `$HOME`.

Comment: See [there](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01). Solaris /bin/sh before Solaris 11 was the Bourne shell, not a POSIX shell. The POSIX sh was in /usr/xpg4/bin or /usr/xpg6/bin. POSIX doesn't specify the path of its `sh`.

Comment: Note that `bash` before bash4 used to perform globbing upon tilde expansion (try `HOME='/*' bash -c 'echo /*'`). So `HOME=/*; [ "$HOME" = ~ ]` would return an error there.

Comment: @MichaelHomer: As POSIX defined, the shell will use [getpwnam()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwnam.html). Could you please give me any reference about `bash` behavior?

Comment: @cuonglm I checked the source code. It [ultimately](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/tilde/tilde.c#n364) [calls](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c#n664) `get_current_user_info`, which [uses `getpwuid` on all platforms but Tandem](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c#n1676).

Comment: **great answer** (concise (**answers the question on the first line**). through research and citations. clear writing. also talks about the deeper nuances.). Thanks!