# Weird bash expansion of ~bin

Tags: bash

Today I accidentally typed `ls ~bin`
I wanted to type `~bak` - that's my junk backup folder, but `~b<tab>` deceived me.

Instead I got this:

```
$ ls ~bin
core_perl                             fogcoord                     lftp                           pcmanfm                                 snmpvacm
site_perl                             fold                         lftpget                        

... many miles of output ...
```

Could anyone kindly explain what the hell happened here? Works also with `cd`, for example.

There is no such folder (or symlink) in pwd - it's the real /bin. I also tried `ls ~etc`, but that didn't work.

Here's my ls:

```
$ alias ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto --group-directories-first -h'
```

Comment: This is called [`tilde expansion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html); so `~bin` is a `tilde-prefix`. _If none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the tilde-prefix following the_ `~` _are treated as a possible login name from the user database._ See also [Does ~ always equal $HOME](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146671)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `bin` user with home `/bin`:

```
$ getent passwd bin
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/bin/false
```

Now `~bin` refers to the home directory of the bin user which is `/bin` and contains all the many miles of commands.

The same way `~etc` does not work, because there is no etc user.

Comment: Oh, that's odd. Any clue *why* there is such user?

Comment: @MightyPork Read [The Advanced Bash Scripting Guide - Non Interactive Shells](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html).  IIRC bin happens to be a non-interactive user.