# Make can't find command, but the command works in shell

Tags: path, make

I have `make` installed, I have the `riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu` toolchain installed.

I have added `riscv/bin` to my path. I can successfully execute any of the toolchain commands in the shell. e.g. `riscv32-unknown-linux gnu-as ... hello.s -o boot.o` works.

When i run `which riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-as`, there is nothing printed to the terminal.

When I run `make` in the directory of my makefile i get

```
riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-as -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32 hello.s -o hello.o
make: riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-as: Command not found
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'hello.o' failed
make: *** [hello.o] Error 127
```

It seems this is a problem with my path? I'm not sure why which and make can't find it, but I can execute it just fine.

** EDIT **

> ~/.profile

```
export PATH="~/riscv/bin:$PATH"
```

The only thing I can think of is something with the path is weird, this is on WSL

Comment: Did you add that directory to your `PATH` by editing you shell's startup files (which one), or did you just add it for the current session by modifying `PATH` on the command line, or both?

Comment: @Kusalananda it is in my `.profile`

Comment: @Kusalananda you can see my edits.

Comment: Did you also adjust the path in the Makefile ? `export PATH := /absolute/path/to/your/home/dir/riscv/bin:$(PATH)` should do it

Comment: Remove the double quotes from that assignment to `PATH` in `.profile`, or use `$HOME` rather than `~`, or set `SHELL=/bin/bash` in your Makefile.  I'm sure there's a duplicate question somewhere on the site...

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/151850) and [Does ~ always equal $HOME](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/146671)  (while neither of them are _exact_ duplicates, they point to the issue; what's lacking is the special treatment of tilde in `$PATH` by the `bash` shell which expands tilde even though it's quoted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tilde character (`~`) does not usually expand to your home directory when it is used within double quotes.  If you look at your `$PATH` value, you will see that it contains a *literal* tilde, not the full path to you home directory (which it would have done if you hadn't double quoted the value in the assignment).

The shell that `make` uses to execute shell commands (`/bin/sh`, which may be the `dash` shell), and your `which` command, does not do an extra tilde expansion step on the values in `$PATH`.  This is why both `make` and `which` fail to find that command that you need to use.

The `bash` shell, on the other hand, does an extra tilde expansion step when examining the `$PATH`, so this is why you can use that command on the command line.

In this scenario, it is `bash` which is the odd one out, as utilities are not required to expand the tilde when they are using the `$PATH` variable.

Solutions:

1. Use `$HOME` rather than `~` in your `.profile`.  `$HOME` always behaves like a normal variable.
2. Don't quote the value in the assignment (it's not needed anyway).
3. Make `make` use `bash` for running the shell commands in the Makefile by setting the `make` variable `SHELL` to the path of the `bash` executable on your system (I would not do this as I would argue that it's the value of you `$PATH` that is wrong, not the `/bin/sh` shell's handling of it).

Further reading:

- [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesn)'t-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes
- [Does ~ always equal $HOME](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146671/does-always-equal-home)

Also note that since `PATH` is already exported (it's an environment variable), you never have to `export` it in your shell's startup files.