# Python subprocess call to insmod produce undefined symbol error, it works from std shell

Tags: ubuntu, python

I need to register a specific kernel module (https://github.com/504ensicsLabs/LiME) in Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo insmod /path/to/lime.ko path=~/dump.raw format=raw
```

from a python script.
I tried using
`os.system() ; subprocess.run()/call()/Popen() - shell=True/False` .
I explicitely imported the .bashrc environment and it all failed with unknown symbol in module error while it works from the command line.
The python script runs with root privileges.
What can be the point I am missing ? What can be the difference between subprocess and the direct shell ? Is it linked to the special nature of the module I try to install ?
The error is

```
insmod: error inserting 'path/to/lime.ko': Unknown symbol in module
```

Comment: Why are you importing .bashrc? That's probably the issue since many default .bashrc files are set up to exit if they are being read by non-interactive shells. More importantly, please [edit] your question and show us the exact error you get and the exact code you use to get the error.

Comment: Effectively this was useless, just an attempt I made. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's the cause of your problem, but note that the `~` in `cmd path=~/dump.raw` is only expanded by the `bash` and `mksh` shells (in the case of `bash` only when what's left of the `=` looks like a valid variable name) when their respective `posix` option is not enabled (and for `bash`, that `posix` option is enabled when invoked as `sh`) and by the `zsh` shell when its `magicequalsubst` option is enabled.

Not in other shells. For `sh`, POSIX requires `echo path=~` to output `path=~`.

So unless your `sh` is a build of `mksh` without the `posix` mode enabled by default, if run from within `python` using a shell (which will be `sh`), that `~` won't be expanded to your home directory.

Here, use:

```
sudo insmod /path/to/lime.ko path="$HOME/dump.raw" format=raw
```

instead. Or get `python` to retrieve the value of the `HOME` environment variable to construct that `path=....` argument if not invoking a shell.

For further reading on the subject of `~` expansion, see [Does ~ always equal $HOME](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146671)

Comment: For what it's worth, on my Arch (`/bin/sh -> bash`), running `os.system("ls ~")` in a python3 shell correctly runs `ls $HOME`. Maybe python doesn't default to `/bin/sh`? I tested, and it also works if I first `export SHELL=/bin/sh` and then run `python3`. Could python be reading my shell from `/etr/password`?

Comment: @terdon, `ls ~` is not the same as `echo path=~`. See the linked Q&A for details.

Comment: Oooh, I just straced `ls ~` and `/bin/sh ls ~` and saw the difference. `sh` will pass `~` to `ls` and it is `ls` itself that expands it. Thanks!

Comment: @terdon. No `ls` doesn't expand tildes. `/bin/sh ls ~` would try to interpret `ls` as a shell script. `/bin/sh -c ls ~` would run `ls` without argument and list the current directory. But again here, the issue is about `~` expansion when that `~` occurs *in the middle* of shell word, not as the first character.

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick and correct answer. Replacing the '~/file.raw' with '"$HOME/file.raw"' well solves this problem.