# What is the difference between $ cd /home and $ cd ~ in ubuntu docker container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

Inside the Ubuntu docker container, `cd /home` and `cd ~` are pointing to different locations.

`cd ~` is going to `/root` folder while cd /home is going to /home. But in general ~ is synonymous with the home directory in Ubuntu. But why is it different in the Ubuntu docker container?

Comment: "`~` is synonymous with the home directory in Ubuntu" – But the home directory is almost always something other than `/home`. For me it's `/home/kamil` and for root it's `/root`.

Comment: Related: [Does ~ always equal $HOME](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146671)

Answer (score 1):

You are root and root's home is in /root. You can check it in /etc/passwd. You would get the same behavior on native installation.

Answer (score 1):

`cd ~` changes to the home-directory of the actual user. Where the home-directory is, is configured in the passwd-map (or -file (`/etc/passwd`)).

If you're working as root, `cd ~` brings you to the home-directory of the user `root`. Which is `/root` in most cases.

If you're working as `user1` and that users home-directory is defined as `/home/user1` in `/etc/passwd/`, `cd ~` brings you to `/home/user1`.

`~[user]` is just some shell-shortcut (in bash and some other shells, not all of them). If you leave out the user, internally the actual user is substituted.

So, as `root` you could do `cd ~user1` and that would change the directory to `/home/user1`.

Comment: plain `~` without an username uses `$HOME`, not the user database, at least in Bash and zsh