# Shebang starting with `//`?

Tags: shell, shell-script, osx, shebang, slash

I'm confused about following script (`hello.go`).

```
//usr/bin/env go run $0 $@ ; exit

package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

It can execute. (on MacOS X 10.9.5)

```
$ chmod +x hello.go
$ ./hello.go
hello, world
```

I haven't heard about shebang starting with `//`. And it still working when I insert a blank line at the top of the script. Why does this script work?

Comment: `//&>/dev/null;x="${0%.*}";[ ! "$x" -ot "$0" ]||(rm -f "$x";cc -o "$x" "$0")&&exec "$x" "$@"` [`...`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12907/1114)

Comment: following @g-man and Jörg comments below, and according to gilles answer ( http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/27616 ), this trick should use `///....` instead of `//...` to be the most compatible!

Comment: This won't correctly handle arguments (or location in a directory) with spaces without more quotes: `go run "$0" "$@"`

Comment: See also: [Stack Overflow: What's the appropriate Go shebang line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7707178/4561887)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It isn't a shebang, it is just a script that gets run by the default shell.  The shell executes the first line

```
//usr/bin/env go run $0 $@ ; exit
```

which causes `go` to be invoked with the name of this file, so the result is that this file is run as a go script and then the shell exits without looking at the rest of the file.

But why start with `//` instead of just `/` or a proper shebang `#!` ?

This is because the file need to be a valid go script, or go will complain.  In go, the characters `//` denote a comment, so go sees the first line as a comment and does not attempt to interpret it.  The character `#` however, does not denote a comment, so a normal shebang would result in an error when go interprets the file.

This reason for the syntax is just to build a file that is both a shell script and a go script without one stepping on the other.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know that shells don't care about the number of slashes in a path. Bug or feature? I'm surprised that `///bin//ls` and `ls ~//.///.ssh/` runs fine.

Comment: It's handled by the kernel, not the shell; see Gilles's answer to [How Linux handles multiple path separators (/home////username///file)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/80216).

Comment: @HermanTorjussen Feature - the synax of paths is pretty well defined, allowing lots of useful variants - and with power comes complexity: `/` as path suffix is defined as `/.`; When `a` is not a symlink, `a` is the same as `a/` which is the same as `a/.` Thera are cases where a path can get an additional `/` with no change in meaning. When deriving a canonical path, there is a normalisation step contracting consecutive slashes to one. Granted, it's not a clean part of the formal syntax, though.

Comment: Actually, POSIX says that multiple slashes are the same as a single slash *except* when there are exactly two slashes exactly at the very beginning of the path. As is the case here. In that case, the interpretation of the path is implementation-dependent: "If a pathname begins with two successive <slash> characters, the first component following the leading <slash> characters may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading <slash> characters shall be treated as a single <slash> character."

Comment: So, to make it portable one should instead write `///usr/bin/env go run $0 $@ ; exit`...

Comment: @casey how the line "hello, world" is getting printed if the shell exits after the first line?

Comment: @geek the shell exits but not before launching the go interpreter. Go is printing hello world, not the shell.

Comment: Apparently a triple backslash in front is "more standards compliant". See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30082862/4561887).

Answer (score 8):

It runs because by default executable file is assumed to be /bin/sh script. I.e. if you didn't specify any particular shell - it is #!/bin/sh.

The // is just ignored in paths - you can consider is at as single '/'.

So you can consider that you have shell script with first line:

```
/usr/bin/env go run $0 $@ ; exit
```

What does this line do? It runs 'env' with paramenters 'go run $0 $@'. there 'go' is command and 'run $0 $@' are args and exits script afterwards. $0 is this script name. $@ are original script arguments. So this line runs go which runs this script with it's arguments

There are quite interesting details, as pointed in comments, that two slashes are implementation-defined, and this script would become POSIX-correct if it specify three or more slashes. Refer to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html for details on how slashes should be handled in paths.

Note also that there is another mistake in script the $@ it's correct to use "$@" instead, because otherwise if any parameter contains spaces it will be split to many parameters. For example you can't pass file name with spaces if you not using the "$@"

This particular script obviously rely on the idea that '//' is equal to '/'

Comment: "The // is just ignored in paths" – That's not guaranteed: "If a pathname begins with two successive <slash> characters, the first component following the leading <slash> characters may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner" (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html)

Comment: Very interesting, updated answer.

Comment: ...AFS in particular implemented // differently, but it's not common anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for C++ (and C if that C allows // for comments)

`//usr/bin/env sh -c 'p=$(expr '"_$0"' : "_\(.*\)\.[^.]*"); make $p > /dev/null && $p'; exit`