# Bash script class path issue with java

Tags: bash, environment-variables, java, su

Content of `/opt/scripts/jvm/jvm.script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_HOME='/java'
PATH="$PATH:/$JAVA_HOME/bin"
java -cp ./classes:./lib com.mystuff.bar.foo.myclass &
```

Content of `/etc/init.d/init.script.sh`

```
home='/opt/scripts/jvm'
program=jvm.script.sh
su scriptuser -c "$home/$program"
```

`/opt/scripts/jvm` is symlinked to `/data/shellscripts` (meaning `/data/shellscripts` exists as a real directory).

Running the init script fails with `cannot find class com.mystuff.bar.foo.myclass`
but if I su to the same user and run it, it works, why?

When I run `su scriptuser -c 'declare -p JAVA_HOME'` I get `JAVA_HOME not found`, but if I su to the user first (using `su scriptuser`) and run it, I get `JAVA_HOME="/java"`

This may sound crazy, but it seems to fix the issue if I add a trailing slash to the home variable in the init script.

So:

```
home='/opt/scripts/jvm'
```

becomes

```
home='/opt/scripts/jvm/'
```

It almost seems like something environmental is messing with the way the symlinks are being handled.

Comment: What is the output of `declare -p JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging When I run su scriptuser -c 'declare -p JAVA_HOME' I get JAVA_HOME not found, but if I su to the user first and run it, I get JAVA_HOME="/java".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra information, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments.

Comment: "but if I su to the same user and run it, it works" – How do you do that, with `su scriptuser` or with `su - scriptuser`?

Comment: I become scriptuser via su scriptuser. This seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a confusing question with the paths and su'ing.  When you run this command:

`$java -cp ./classes:./lib com.mystuff.bar.foo.myclass`

And get 'class not found', that means java is not able to find that class in ./classes or ./lib.  If you either

a) use absolute paths, or 
b) cd to the right place before running the command (su scriptuser -c "cd $home ; ./$program")

it will work more reliably.

As for why adding a "/" to home makes a difference, that does seem very strange.  You could break out strace/truss and see what system calls the command is making. This answer quotes from the posix spec:

[How linux handles multiple path separators (/home////username///file)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file)

and says "For programs that act on a directory entry, if foo is a symbolic link to a directory, then passing foo/ is a way to make the program act on the directory instead of the symbolic link."

Comment: I am not confused about that, I am sure you are right, but I only have control over the init script, not the bash script which calls the JVM.  I understand that class not found is because the relative pathing in the class path is not working as expected.  What I am confused about is why does it make a difference if I su to the user and run the jvm script versus calling the script with su USER -c script if my working directory is the same in both cases.

Comment: Not saying you're confused, meant to say the question is confusing with all the paths and su'ing ;-)  I've edited my answer to suggest a way to make it the same no matter what, as well as added a link to another question that may explain the difference with the extra slash.

Comment: Thanks for your input!  Because of my inability to edit the called script, I am going to chalk this up to environmental issues and relative pathing.