# Difference between / and //

Tags: bash, coreutils, pwd

On the bash prompt one, three or more slashes (/,///,////, ...) are treated as a single slash, whereas two slashes (//) are left as is:

```
12:07 $ cd /
12:07 $ pwd
/
12:07 $ cd //
12:07 $ pwd
//
12:07 $ ls
bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home  initrd.img  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var  vmlinuz
12:07 $ cd ///
12:07 $ pwd
/
12:07 $ ls
bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home  initrd.img  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var  vmlinuz
```

Usual suspects' versions:

```
12:07 $ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

12:20 $ dpkg-query -s coreutils | grep Version
Version: 8.21-1ubuntu5
```

Comment: duplicates: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690828/what-does-double-slash-in-cd-mean-in-linux) && [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file)

Answer (score 1):

For displaying the current directory `bash` keeps some internal state that doesn't necessarily corresponds to the actual (shortest) path to the current directory. This helps in keeping the path if you `cd` through soft links.

The `cd //` (but also when doing e.g. `cd //tmp`) do not seem to trigger a sanitization of the internal path displayed by `pwd`, but more than two `/` seem to trigger this.

Comment: I guess `//` does not need sanitisation, since it is implementation-defined. See: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11. Thanks to @rush for the links above.