# Print last character in the given path

Tags: shell, shell-script, awk

I am trying to concat `"comnp.dat_CY*"` files into one file. File name, source path and destination path are the parameters. I am trying to find the last character in the path to check if it is `"/"` or not. But when I try to do that I am getting error. Below is my script

```
if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "Script requires 3 inputs"
    echo "1. File pattern (comnp.dat_CY)"
    echo "2. Source path"
    echo "3. Destination path"
    exit
fi

last_char1 = `echo $2|awk -F  '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}`
last_char2 = `echo $3|awk -F  '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}`

if [ $last_char1 != "/" ];then
    ap_src_path = "$2/"
fi
if [ $last_char2 != "/" ];then
    ap_dest_path = "$3/"
fi

cat $ap_src_path$1* > $ap_dest_pathcomnp.dat
```

Below are my errors:

```
comnp.sh: Broken pipe
comnp.sh[14]: last_char1:  not found
comnp.sh[15]: last_char2:  not found
comnp.sh[17]: test: argument expected
comnp.sh[20]: test: argument expected
```

What is wrong in my script?

I am using `ksh AIX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you **cannot** use space around `=`. The shell is very picky about that. And `awk` commands are totally buggy.

Moreover, in 2014 better use `$( )` than backticks. So `awk` lines should be :

```
last_char1=$(echo "$2" | awk '{print $NF}' FS='')
last_char2=$(echo "$3" | awk '{print $NF}' FS='')
```

check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: I have tried your solution and i am getting the output what i required but when i pass the path without `/` it is showing error like `comnp.sh[18]: ap_src_path:  not found
comnp.sh[21]: ap_dest_path:  not found` but in this case also it is giving output.what could be the reason

Answer (score 3):

Variable assignment in shell syntax is not allowed to have spaces.
`last_char = ...` is a command called `last_char` with the arguments `=` and `....`. `last_char=...` is an assignment that stores `...` in the shell variable `last_char`.

---

This is a much more efficient and direct way to do what you want:

```
case $2 in
  */) ap_src_path=$2;; 
  *) ap_src_path=$2/;;
esac
case $3 in
  */) ap_dest_path=$3;;
  *) ap_dest_path=$3/;;
esac
```

You don't need to extract the last character to do a simple comparison. Also, command substitution is inefficient and clunky for simple shell variable manipulation like this.

---

More importantly, you don't need to do any of this at all. For the most part, Unix path resolution does not care about [duplicated slashes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1910/9537), so `path///to//a/file` is just as valid as `path/to/a/file`. In scripts, you can take advantage of this by simply not worrying about duplicate `/`. In other words you can replace the entire script with

```
if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
   # ... same as above ...
fi
pattern=$1
ap_src_path=$2
ap_dst_path=$3

cat "$ap_src_path/$pattern"* > "$ap_dest_path/compn.dat"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
last_char1=$(echo ${2:${#2}-1}); 
last_char2=$(echo ${3:${#3}-1}); 

if [[ "$last_char1" != "/" ]]; then
```

Tips:

- Use $(*command*), instead of old `*command*`: [Reference](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)
- Use [[ ]], instead of [ ]: [Reference](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

Comment: If you use `bash` your command can be shorter `last_char1=${2: -1})`(do not miss space between `:` and `-`)

Comment: @Albert I have tried your solution but i am getting error like `comnp.sh[9]: ${2:${#2}-1}: bad substitution`. I am using `ksh AIX`

Comment: @Aravind Albert's answer assumed you were using `bash`. If you are using `ksh` there may be feature differences causing your error. See my answer for something that works in all shells.

Comment: Yes, I assumed bash, sorry ;) By the way @Costas, I knew there was a simpler solution but I didn't remember the space. Nice.

Comment: @Aravind May be for `ksh` you should calculate `position=$((${#2} - 1))` before and use `last_char1=${2:${position}:1}`

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems with your script. Spaces around `=` should not be present, single quotes `'` are not paired, and additionally `awk -F` requires a parameter - a field separator, so you should rather write `awk -F '' '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}'`.

But in fact if you use any reasonable shell like `bash` or `zsh` then you can simply write

```
cat "${ap_src_path}/${1}*" > "${ap_dest_path}/comnp.dat"
```

without a need of last characters and all those `if` conditions. Possible additional `/` are just ignored, so for example a path `/var//log///mysql////mysql.log` is perfectly fine syntax.