# When does adding `/` to a directory change its meaning?

Tags: directory

When does adding `/` to a directory change its meaning?

E.g. from Linux in a Nutshell:

> Transfer the entire directory proj to the /planning directory on
>   remote host ourhub:
>
> ```
> $ rsync -r proj/ ourhub:/planning
> ```
>
> Transfer the files and subdirectories under proj to the /planning
>   directory on remote host ourhub:
>
> ```
> $ rsync -r proj ourhub:/planning
> ```

But `ls proj` and `ls proj/` are the same. (I think I have asked something similar before, but I couldn't find it). Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the tools you used.

Comment: any general rules help me to tell?

Comment: I think there's no general rule for this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5498231

Comment: For the general case, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file

Answer (score 2):

There's no system-wide rule; but, the behavior you see in `rsync` is documented near the beginning of the rsync man page:

```
          rsync -avz foo:src/bar /data/tmp

   This would recursively transfer all files from the directory src/bar on the machine foo into the /data/tmp/bar directory on the local machine. The files are transferred
   in  "archive" mode, which ensures that symbolic links, devices, attributes, permissions, ownerships, etc. are preserved in the transfer.  Additionally, compression will
   be used to reduce the size of data portions of the transfer.

          rsync -avz foo:src/bar/ /data/tmp

   A trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid creating an additional directory level at the destination.  You can think of a trailing / on a  source  as
   meaning  "copy  the contents of this directory" as opposed to "copy the directory by name", but in both cases the attributes of the containing directory are transferred
   to the containing directory on the destination.  In other words, each of the following commands copies the files in  the  same  way,  including  their  setting  of  the
   attributes of /dest/foo:
```