# Why do I have double slash here?

Tags: bash, shell, filenames, which, slash

```
$ which mycommand
/home/t/program_files/document/other edits//mycommand
```

Why do I have double slash `//` here?

Answer (score 6):

`which` searches your PATH. It happens that `mycommand` is found in a `$PATH` entry with a trailing slash: `/home/t/program_files/document/other edits/`. `which` concatenates the directory, a `/` as separator, and the command name to build the filename to check; when the directory has a trailing slash, this results in two slashes.

[Multiple slashes are equivalent to a single one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file), so this is completely inoccuous.

P.S. [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you have put a trailing forward slash (`/`) while adding the location `/home/t/program_files/document/other edits` in `$PATH`.

You might have used:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/t/program_files/document/other\ edits/
```

You need to use to get rid of trailing `/`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/t/program_files/document/other\ edits
```

Although this is not that much of a problem AFAIK as shell will treat `//` as `/`.

Comment: Is putting a trailing forward slash (/)  in $PATH bad?

Comment: @Tim: Check my edits..shell will treat `//` as `/` so wont be a problem