# how to strip the last slash of the directory path?

Tags: shell-script, filenames, string

I have a script which requires an directory as one argument. 
I want to support the two form: one is like

```
a/b/c
```

(no slash at the end) and another is like

```
 a/b/c/
```

(has slash at the end).

My question: given either of the two form, how can I just keep the first form unchanged and strip the last slash of the second form to convert it to the first form.

Comment: Not that it should be much of a problem - a double slash anywhere except at the start is equivalent to a single slash, so don't worry about joining them using `/`.

Comment: @muru I did not know this before :).

Comment: Here is a good Q/A on [Multiple Consecutive Path Separators](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1910/2343)

Comment: @muru A slash at the end can make a difference, such as the difference between acting on a symlink and acting on the directory it points to, or the source argument of `rsync`.

Comment: @Gilles indeed, but as you can see, I'm talking of joining paths.

Comment: You'll run into trouble parsing paths as strings if you're not careful - consider `a/////b/c` or `a/../a/.././//a/b/c////`. The best solution is usually `cd` - `{ cd -- "$1" && cd - || exit; } >/dev/null" ` which will handle all of that correctly, automatically print a properly formatted diag for error and put a full path in `$OLDPWD`. Use `cd -P` to automatically canonicalize symlinks in your argument to absolute paths. And strip `$PWD` from the head of `$OLDPWD` for relative paths like `dir=${OLDPWD#"$PWD"/}; [ -n "${dir##/*}" ] || ! echo not relative\!`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
dir=${1%/}
```

will take the script's first parameter and remove a trailing slash if there is one.

Answer (score 17):

To remove a trailing slash if there is one, you can use the suffix removal [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) construct present in all POSIX-style shells:

```
x=${x%/}
```

There are a few complications. This only removes a single slash, so if you started with `a/b/c//` then you'll still end up with a slash. Furthermore, if the original path was `/`, you need to keep the slash. Here's a more complex solution that takes care of these cases:

```
case $x in
  *[!/]*/) x=${x%"${x##*[!/]}"};;
  *[/]) x="/";;
esac
```

Alternatively, in ksh, or in bash after `shopt -s extglob`:

```
[[ x = *[!/] ]] || x=${x%%*(/)}
```

Note that in many cases, it doesn't matter that there is a trailing slash. It does matter if the argument is a symbolic link to a directory: with a trailing slash, the argument designates the directory, whereas with no trailing slash, the argument designates the symbolic link itself. It also matters with a few other programs, for example the source argument of `rsync` is treated differently depending on the presence of a trailing slash.

Answer (score 5):

`realpath` resolves given path. Among other things it also removes trailing slashes. Use `-s` to prevent following simlinks

```
DIR=/tmp/a///
echo $(realpath -s $DIR)
# output: /tmp/a
```