Cannot update bash_profile, syntax error in line 411 .nvm/nvm.sh
I'm getting a 'command not found' error when I run terminal.  As far as I know I have to input into my bash profile the following syntax:
export PATH="/users/me/documents/pcode/venv3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coverage:${PATH}"

When I then go to update my bash_profille I run:
source ~/.bash_profile

But then I get the following error message:
.nvm/nvm.sh: line 411: syntax error near unexpected token 
line 411: `    *[!/]*/)'

Tracking down the above file at line 411 we find:
# Auto detect the NVM_DIR when not set
if [ -z "${NVM_DIR-}" ]; then
  # shellcheck disable=SC2128
  if [ -n "${BASH_SOURCE-}" ]; then
    # shellcheck disable=SC2169,SC3054
    NVM_SCRIPT_SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
  fi
  # shellcheck disable=SC2086
  NVM_DIR="$(nvm_cd ${NVM_CD_FLAGS} "$(dirname "${NVM_SCRIPT_SOURCE:-$0}")" >/dev/null && \pwd)"
  export NVM_DIR
else
  # https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198289
  case $NVM_DIR in
    *[!/]*/)
      NVM_DIR="${NVM_DIR%"${NVM_DIR##*[!/]}"}"
      export NVM_DIR
      nvm_err "Warning: \$NVM_DIR should not have trailing slashes"
    ;;
  esac
fi
unset NVM_SCRIPT_SOURCE 2>/dev/null

I didn't write the above code and do not know how to fix it.

There is nothing obviously wrong with the code that you show. Adding the export statement to your ~/.bash_profile file should not cause a freak syntax error in a seemingly unrelated file.  How is nvm.sh invoked?

Actually, I don't remember what that nvm file even does so I just commented it out of my bash profile.  But now I still can't update my bassh_profile.  when I run .~/.bash_profile I get the error message: source: .: is a directory

Well I solved the 'command not found' error but I would still like to know why I can't update my bash other than by closing a terminal window then reopening it.  When I run source ~/.bash_profile I get no such directory.  But that's false. when I run open -a Finder /Users/me/.bash_profile it opens my bash_profile

(1) Thank you for not posting all 400+ lines of .nvm/nvm.sh, or posting just one line.  But what lines are those?  411 through 431?  391 through 411?  Something else?  (2) You have said twice that you cannot update bash_profile.  What do you mean?  How are you trying to update it, and what happens when you do that?  … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  (3) You say, “When I run source ~/.bash_profile I get no such directory.”  Well, the obvious possibility is that you are successfully sourcing your .bash_profile, and that some problem in that file is causing the error message.  What do you get if you say ls -ld ~/.bash_profile?  (4) Take a deep breath and [edit] your question to show what you’re doing and what happens.  Are you still getting the “syntax error” and “is a directory” errors?  Please do not provide critical information in comments.

You can get an error message similar to that if you have an invisible character (like a non-breaking space) at the start of the line. But the error message from Bash should contain the offending token at the end of the first line, and the file name at the start of the second line too. Is that the exact error message you get?  You may want to add your shell version, and to check what the file actually contains. Perhaps with something like grep -A 5 -e 'case.*NVM_DIR' | od -c or such.
