# 'cd //; pwd' # What's happening here?

Tags: path, cd-command

A coworker just pointed out something odd, and I'm curious what the explanation might be.

On the systems I've tried, cd /', 'cd //', and 'cd ///' all have the effect of changing directory to the file system root. However, 'cd /; pwd' and 'cd ///; pwd' return a response of '/', but 'cd //; pwd' returns '//', even though it's the file system root, as in the other cases.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some systems have used double-slashes to represent hostnames on a network, e.g.,

```
//host/usr/bin
```

and POSIX gives a nod to this usage in the description of [`cd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html):

> An implementation may further simplify *curpath* by removing any trailing  characters that are not also leading *`<slash>`* characters, replacing multiple non-leading consecutive  characters with a single *`<slash>`*, and replacing **three** or more leading  characters with a single *`<slash>`*. If, as a result of this canonicalization, the *curpath* variable is null, no further steps shall be taken.

For example, Apollo workstations did this (see *[Why the //, #, etc?](https://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/FAQ.html#etc)* in Tim Berners-Lee's FAQ).

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible sources of `pwd` on my system: `pwd` the `bash` builtin, and `/usr/bin/pwd`, which comes from GNU coreutils. When I issue `cd //; pwd` (using the shell builtin), it types `//`. However, when I issue `cd //; /usr/bin/pwd` (using the external), it types `/`. The actual working directory in both cases, as evidenced by `ls` output and such, is always the same (the FS root).

Thus, the answer seems to be that there are two different concepts involved: the shell's idea of its working directory, and the actual process CWD. The builtin `pwd` queries the former, while `/usr/bin/pwd` (and any other binary) will only have access to the latter, and it's only the former which knows anything about `//`. Why the shell's concept of a working directory distinguishes between `/` and `//`, and what `//` is supposed to mean, I have no idea.

EDIT: Some searching comes across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209833/strange-command-prompt-behavior-of-cd), which sheds some light. Apparently the weird behavior is standards-compliant, though it is still weird.

Comment: It seems that semantically, any more than one `/` in a sequence is effectively parsed as one; `cd //////var///tmp` and `cd /var/tmp` have the same practical effect vis-a-vis where you end up on the filesystem.

Comment: This is the case, it seems, with the exception of exactly two slashes at the beginning of a path, which "may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner". (SUS, linked [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-does-linux-handle-multiple-consecutive-path-separators-home-username)).