# Why does grep sometimes return directories with two slashes?

Tags: grep

I just ran `grep -ri foo someDir/`

I got back

`someDir//foo/bar/baz: onDelete() {`

Does the double forward slash just mean that everything to the left of it was in the dir argument you provided to grep?

Comment: I think this problem will not occur if you do this: grep -ri delete someDir ...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run the command:

```
grep -r <pattern> <directory>
```

it prints all the filenames as `<directory>/<filename>`. If you put a slash at the end of `<directory>`, it will be included in that, so you end up with a double slash.

The code could have been smart enough to notice when the original directory name ends with `/` and omit it when printing filenames, but they didn't bother. I think the only special case it makes is for the root directory, e.g.

```
grep -r pattern /
```

will print `/foo/bar/baz` rather than `//foo/bar/baz`. This is because POSIX specifies that a sequence of slashes is treated equivalently to a single slash *except* that two slashes at the beginning have implementation-dependent meaning (this is because some network file system mechanisms made use of syntax like `//server/pathname`). See [How does Linux handle multiple consecutive path separators (/home////username///file)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-does-linux-handle-multiple-consecutive-path-separators-home-username)

Comment: +1. worth noting is that (with the possible exception of some badly written scripts)  unix doesn't care if a pathname has extra `/`s in it.  `/path/to/filename` is functionally the same as `////path//to/////////////filename`.   This is **extremely** useful when writing scripts that work with directory and filenames in variables, just append them to each other with an extra `/` and it'll Just Work.  also worth noting is that most URI types require `protocolname://` at the start....the double-`/` matters there.