# Is it ok that find displays double forward-slash?

Tags: find, filenames, macos, slash

Is it a bug that, when I `find ./path/here/` I get:

```
./path/here//foo
./path/here//bar
```

I know `find` wants me to specify the path without the trailing slash, but surely it can detect the path that tab-completing leaves me with and adjust its output accordingly. Is there any reason why it doesn't?

Comment: Submit a bug report to Apple. If enough people complain, they'll fix it.

Answer (score 8):

Technically, it's a bug, because [POSIX states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) that

> all pathnames for other files encountered in the hierarchy shall consist of the concatenation of the current path operand, a <slash> **if the current path operand did not end in one**, and the filename relative to the path operand

But [the double slash doesn't make any difference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-does-linux-handle-multiple-consecutive-path-separators-home-username), so `./path/here//foo` and `./path/here/foo` are always the same file. (A double slash does make a difference if it's at the start of the path on a few Unix variants. If yours does then hopefully `find` treats this case specially.)

Answer (score 1):

For the record, one reason one might use `find some/dir/` instead of `find some/dir` is when `some/dir` is actually a symlink to a directory and you do want `find` to find files in the directory pointed to by that symlink.

But, in that case, there's a better alternative:

```
find -H some/dir
```

`-H` is an option supported by a few POSIX utilities (`ls`, `cp`, `chmod`...) which tells the utility to follow symlinks passed as arguments (and just those, not to be confused with `-L`/`-follow` which causes `find` to follow *every* symlink, those passed as arguments but also those found during directory traversal).

That's still not functionally equivalent to `find some/dir/` in the case where `some/dir` is actually not a directory. In that case, `find some/dir/` would fail with a *Not a directory* error while `find -H some/dir` would list that  non-directory file.