# What does //1/ mean

Tags: ksh, qnx

QNX4 operating system using Korn Shell.
This is in a .profile file.

```
export VARDIR=//1/usr/pvcs
```

What does the
//1/
represent?

Comment: Related: [On what systems is //foo/bar different from /foo/bar?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/256497)

Answer (score 28):

[For the most part, multiple slashes are equivalent to a single slash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-does-linux-handle-multiple-consecutive-path-separators-home-username/1919#1919). There's one exception: paths beginning with exactly two slashes (`//foo/…`, as opposed to `/foo/…` or `///foo/…`) have a different meaning on some Unix variants. The meaning is often to access a remote resource with a path like `//hostname/dir1/dir2/dir3/file`. (Windows does this too, with `\\hostname\dir1\dir2\dir3\file`.)

QNX is one of those variants. On QNX4 with the FLEET distributed processing protocol, `//` followed by a number refers to that node. So `//1/usr/pvcs` on any node refers to the file `/usr/pvcs` on node 1.

(Source: the [QNX6 manual](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_user_guide%2Ffiles.html&cp=13_11_6_1&anchor=PATHNAMES), I can't find official QNX4 documentation online.)

Answer (score -2):

To all indications, the variable is receiving a web path as content.

```
//aaaa/bbbb/cccc/nnnn - 
at where: 
aaaa = server name or IP address; 
bbbb = folder from the logical root of the domain aaaa (web servers can handle this dynamically); 
cccc = bbbb subfolder; 
nnnn = nth subfolder.
```

Comment: It is not an URL, but a special path handled in a particular way on QNX systems.