# Readline: using tab as menu-complete, how do I “accept” the auto-completed directory and display the next level down?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, readline

I'm using the following settings on my readline (~/.inputrc):

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
set menu-complete-display-prefix on
set completion-ignore-case on
"\t": menu-complete
"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward
```

If, for example, there are 3 directories `101`, `102` and `103`, each with three directories inside them `201`, `202` and `203`, each with their own files and I type:

`$ cd 1` <kbd>Tab</kbd>

I get:

`$ cd 101/`

How do I "accept" this completion so that I can then choose the next directory on the next level down? Like so:

`$ cd 1` <kbd>Tab</kbd>

`$ cd 101/` <kbd>SomeKeyCombo</kbd>

`$ cd 101/201/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get `$ cd 101/` type additional slash, so it looks like

```
$ cd 101//
```

and then <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

This double slash [will be equivalent to a single slash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/108618).