# Where can I find a definitive answer for what `*/` means in Bash or Zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, wildcards, slash

I was trying to look into some reference from O'Reilly about Unix and Bash about the meaning of `*/` but couldn't find any.  We can `echo */` and see all the directories.

It seems like it means all "directories" only, while `*` means "all files and directories", but for some reason, many users seem to not know it, and books don't mention it either.

Is there a definitive source that talks about what `*/` means and perhaps its variations?

Comment: [man 7 glob](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html), [man zshexpn](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn) and scroll to `FILENAME GENERATION`

Comment: and Globs work on filenames ... Think what `for i in *; do` does?

Answer (score 19):

The [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) is the definitive reference on how unix tools should behave. The [section on pathname resolution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13) explains the meaning of trailing slashes in file names.

> A pathname that contains at least one non-<slash> character and that ends with one or more trailing <slash> characters shall not be resolved successfully unless the last pathname component before the trailing <slash> characters names an existing directory or a directory entry that is to be created for a directory immediately after the pathname is resolved.

In other words: `foo/` requires `foo` to be an existing directory, or a directory that the program will create (so `mkdir foo/` is permitted). If `foo` is some other type of file (regular file, name piped, etc.), then accessing it as `foo/` must not work.

The sentence above is incomplete: `foo/` is actually a valid way to reference a symbolic link to a directory. This is specified below:

> If a symbolic link is encountered during pathname resolution, the behavior shall depend on whether the pathname component is at the end of the pathname and on the function being performed. If all of the following are true, then pathname resolution is complete:
>
> 1. This is the last pathname component of the pathname.
>   2. The pathname has no trailing .
>   3. The function is required to act on the symbolic link itself, or certain arguments direct that the function act on the symbolic link itself.
>
> In all other cases, the system shall prefix the remaining pathname, if any, with the contents of the symbolic link (…).

In other words: if `foo` is a symbolic link, and the program is supposed to follow symbolic links, then `foo/` is equivalent to the target of the link, which may be a directory. So if `foo` is a symbolic link to a directory, `foo/` is a valid way to refer to this directory. But if `foo` is a symbolic to a regular file or other non-directory, then `foo/` is not a valid way to refer to that file.

Functions such as [`open`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) return the error `ENOTDIR` if given a pathname with a trailing slash that is an existing non-directory.

> [`ENOTDIR`]
>   (…) `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL` are not specified, the path argument contains at least one non-<slash> character and ends with one or more trailing <slash> characters, and the last pathname component names an existing file that is neither a directory nor a symbolic link to a directory (…)

The impact of a slash in `*/` is described implicitly in [the section on pattern matching in `sh`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13). There is no special rule for the `/` in a pattern (other than the rule that it cannot appear in a bracket expression, which is not relevant here). Therefore a `/` in a pattern must match a `/` in a pathname. For example, the pattern `*/` matches `foo/` but not `foo`. Therefore `*/` matches directories and symbolic link to directories, but not regular files, symbolic link to regular files, broken symbolic links, named pipes, etc.

Comment: but interestingly, if a directory is named `foo`, its name is `foo` but not `foo/`... so `*/` doesn't really match it "by name". Unless officially, the name is really `foo/` but we can do `mv foo bar` just as a shorthand.

Comment: I'd say `foo` is the official name, but `foo/` is a valid _path_ which refers to `foo`. Compare this to other patterns: `*/bar`, for instance, matches a `bar` file located in any directory - it's not looking for a file named literally "<anything>/bar", it's looking for a path `<anything> / bar` which locates a valid file. The glob matching isn't matching on a _path_, not a _name_.

Comment: @nonopolarity This view is gibberish. In POSIX, file names, including directory names, must not contain a slash.

Comment: About `zsh` specifically, see the discussion at https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2020/msg00032.html though. You'd expect `*/` to expand to the same as `*(-/M)` (the files of type directory (`/`) after symlink resolution (`-`), `M`arked with `/`), but it doesn't in current versions of `zsh` as it doesn't include directories that are not searchable on systems other than Cygwin (expands to the same dirs as `*/.`)

Comment: actually, the `*` and `**` matching by path makes a lot of sense... so that's why it can be recursive and why `*/` means "anything that can be a path" (or top of the path)

Comment: FWIW, the `glob(3)` function of GNU standard C library (glibc) is broken wrt `*/`. It will also return matching non-directories when the filesystem doesn't support the `dirent->d_type` optimization or when the `GLOB_ALTDIRFUNC` feature is used, and `d_type` is not set to the correct type. Fortunately, most mainstream Linux fs do support `d_type`, and the only critical program which makes use of `GLOB_ALTDIRFUNC` is GNU make, which I have fixed to pass the right `d_type` through. But if you're using some older version of GNU make, it will still blow in your face.

Comment: [Reference](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25659)

Comment: @nonopolarity "Path" and "directory" are not synonyms. "Path" is a name refering to an object in the file system, which consists of a base name preceded by zero or more containing directories. If your current working directory is `/home/bob`, then `foo.txt` and `/home/bob/foo.txt` are both paths to the same file (the former being a relative path, the latter an absolute path.) `*/` only matches directories in the current working directory.

Comment: If we look at it this way, doesn't it make sense? `echo */*.js` shows all possible ways such as `foo/bar.js`, so by the same principle, then `echo */` shows all possible ways `foo/` and `Downloads/`

Comment: I think the first part of this answer misses the point. When globbing, the shell doesn't yet know how the result will be used. `echo */` and `ls */` have the same globbing rules. And `echo */` obviously doesn't care whether the globbed result names a directory or a file; it just prints a string. The relevant part seems to come from one of your earlier [older answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-does-linux-handle-multiple-consecutive-path-separators-home-username). There's an implied `.` after a trailing slash; it's matched as if it were `*/.`

Comment: @MSalters As noted in that answer, the wording in SUSv4 is different from earlier POSIX versions and a trailing slash is no longer defined as equivalent to `*/.` (even if the end result is often the same).

Answer (score 3):

There are several **hints** that a `*/` should match only directories is bash manual (emphasis mine):

1. > *
   >   Matches any string, including the null string.  When the globstar shell option is enabled, and * is used in a pathname expansion context, two adjacent *s used as a single pattern will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  **If followed by a /,**  two  adjacent *s **will match only directories and subdirectories**.

   It is explicit in that a `**/` will match only directories and subdirectories, which may seem to imply that a `*/` should too.
2. > globstar
   >   If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  **If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories match**.

   A repetition of the hint above.

And in the zsh manual:

1. > -g globstring
   >   The  globstring is expanded using filename globbing; it should be quoted to protect it from immediate expansion. The resulting filenames are taken as the possible completions.  Use`` `*(/)' `` **instead of`` `*/' `` for directories**.

   Which explicitly states that a `*/` should mean directories **in some other place**.

But the only real confirmation, comes from ksh manual:

> *
>   Matches any string, including the null string.  When used for filename expansion, if the globstar option is on, two adjacent *'s by itself will match all files and zero or  more  directories  and  subdirectories. If  **followed by a / then only directories and subdirectories will match**.

Which is explicitly clear about what a single `*` should do.

Given that POSIX was mostly based on the way ksh works, and that bash and zsh try to emulate the way ksh works, it is reasonable to expect this same feature will be repeated on all three manuals.

Comment: About `zsh` specifically, see the discussion at https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2020/msg00032.html though. You'd expect `*/` to expand to the same as `*(-/M)` (the files of type directory (`/`) after symlink resolution (`-`), `M`arked with `/`), but it doesn't in current versions of `zsh` as it doesn't include directories that are not searchable on systems other than Cygwin (expands to the same dirs as `*/.`)

Answer (score 1):

You can find some explanation in [the bash manual, Pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)

> 3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching
>
> Any character that appears in a pattern, other than the special
>   pattern characters described below, matches itself. The NUL character
>   may not occur in a pattern. A backslash escapes the following
>   character; the escaping backslash is discarded when matching. The
>   special pattern characters must be quoted if they are to be matched
>   literally.
>
> The special pattern characters have the following meanings:
>
> *
>
> Matches any string, including the null string. When the globstar shell option is enabled, and ‘*’ is used in a **filename expansion
>   context**, two adjacent ‘*’s used as a single pattern will match all
>   files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If followed by
>   a ‘/’, two adjacent ‘*’s will match only directories and
>   subdirectories.

And in [The linux documentation project](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) you find an explanation on `echo` `*`:

> Bash **performs filename expansion** on unquoted command-line arguments.
>   The echo command demonstrates this.
>
> ````
> bash$ echo * a.1 b.1 c.1 t2.sh test1.txt`
>
> bash$ echo t* t2.sh test1.txt
>
> bash$ echo t?.sh t2.sh```
> ````

Comment: But it talks only about `two adjacent ‘*’s`, not about `echo */`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk see my updated answer, although, as I understand "Matches any string, including the null string."  is the explanation for a single *.

Answer (score 0):

The expansion of `*/` means nothing special to the shell. It is exactly the same as expanding `*.txt` will list all **existing pathnames** that end in `.txt`.

For **any** shell, a `*/` will expand to all accessible pathnames that end in a `/`.

The only issue then is to understand when a `pathname` could end in a `/`.

That is only possible when the last filename exists and is a directory.

Explicit confirmation (from man ksh):

> *
>   ... If followed by a / then only directories and subdirectories will match.