# Unix “find” command: display folder/directory type

Tags: find

How do you get `find .` to display the type (directory/file) of an entry? As it is, you can't tell whether an entry is a file or an empty directory.

Comment: Have you looked at the `find` manual page/info page, via `man find` / `info find`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNU version of `find` has an option `-printf`, which can print various pieces of file metadata. For example,

```
find . -printf "%y %p\n"
```

prints the file type (f for regular file, d for directory) and its name.

Linux distros tend to deploy GNU's version of `find`. In case you don't have GNU's `find`, you may need a small script, perhaps

```
find . -exec sh -c 'ls -l "$1" | cut -c1' sh-find "{}" \; -print
```

(refinement of the rather ugly output is left as an exercise to the reader).

Comment: it's not in posix find, but both GNU and *BSD versions of `find` have a `-ls` option for `ls -l` style output.    You can also use `-exec stat ... {} +` if you have a stat that has printf-like options (both GNU and *BSD stat do, but the options and syntax are different)

Comment: Thanks for the addition, @cas.

Answer (score 1):

The `ls` command has a standard option, `-F`, that adds a `/` after directories, `*` after executable files, `@` after symbolic links, and `|` after named pipes (and implementations may add further symbols to this; see your `ls` manual).

To call `ls -F` on each found thing:

```bsh
find . -exec ls -1 -f -d -F {} +
```

I added the `-1` ("dash-one") option to get the results in a single column, `-f` to turn off sorting of results (you'll get the order that `find` finds the pathnames in), and `-d` to list directories, not their contents.

The `{} +` will be replaced by batches of found pathnames, as many as `ls` can be called with at a time.

Example run:

```
$ find . -exec ls -1 -f -d -F {} +
./
./.bash_profile
./.zshrc
./.bashrc
./.yashrc
./dir1/
./dir1/file-1
./dir1/subdir/
./dir1/subdir/file-2
./dir2/
./dir2/file-1
./dir2/subdir/
./dir2/subdir/file-2
```

The pathnames not ending in any particular character are regular files.

Answer (score 0):

The following command is like `find .`, but it adds a trailing slash for files of the type directory:

```
find . ! -type d -print -o -exec printf '%s/\n' {} \;
```

The idea is to indicate directories *and* still get valid existing pathnames in the output.

Notes:

- The command is portable.
- If in place of `.` you use a pathname that ends with `/` (and the directory exists) then, when processing the pathname, `find` will substitute the supplied string instead of `{}`. In effect you get a line that ends with `//`. [This is not a problem unless maybe if you specify the root directory `/` and get exactly `//`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/108618). A workaround is to specify `/.` instead of `/`. An improvement is not to add slash if there's already a trailing slash:

  ```
  find … \( ! -type d -o -path '*/' \) -print -o -exec printf '%s/\n' {} \;
  ```

  where `…` denotes one or more (or zero, if your `find` can take it) starting pathnames. Then you can safely specify `/`.