Behavior of truncating multiple slashes in paths stemming from glob pattern matching
From my limited research it seems that in bash, any multiple slashes after a glob pattern are truncated, like so:
echo ////[h]ome////user////Desktop////test////
# outputs ////home/user/Desktop/test/

echo ////home////user////Desktop////tes[t]////
# outputs ////home////user////Desktop////test/

Is this conclusion correct? Is this behavior defined? If so, where? Is it shared between different shells? Does it have any relevance?
I've read the bash manual and couldn't find anything about this, though I might've missed something. I understand there is no semantic difference between these notations (other than the exception of a leading double slash), just not whether this behavior is intended or purposeful.
Edit: The behavior described is happening in default bash on Ubuntu. Korn shell (/usr/bin/sh) did not truncate any slashes.
Edit 2: Just to clarify:

I'm not asking how Linux handles multiple slashes, it's clear that multiple slashes other than the leading double slash exception have no semantic meaning and may be truncated.
I'm not asking how this behavior impacts anything within the shell pipeline - it clearly doesn't, other than that if the glob expansion is passed down as an argument, it simply has more slashes.
I'm not asking why this happens to paths with glob patterns - it's clear that whatever piece of code handles glob expansion also truncates the slashes that follow the glob.
I'm specifically asking whether this behavior is defined, shared across different shells, intentional or purposeful.


May I ask in what environment? That could narrow down which element "defines" this behavior.

Sounds just like an accident of implementation, likely harmless as multiple /s are equivalent to one in pathname resolutions except for the special case of 2 and only 2 ones at the start on some systems.

FWIW, it's been the case since at least as far back as 2.02 (the earliest version I could try it on). I've not found any other shell that behaved like that, not even ksh which bash tries to copy, suggesting even further that it's just an accident of implementation.

Quite possibly a duplicate of this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-does-linux-handle-multiple-consecutive-path-separators-home-username

If the string contains any glob pattern, the shell tries to expand it as a pathname before it is passed to echo. If there are no * or [] characters, no globbing is done and the string passed to echo is not changed. Only characters after the first glob character are altered.

Yes, that is specifically, explicitly the premise of the question: I'm not asking why this happens to paths with globs while not happening to paths without them - that much is obvious. I'm asking whether the specific behavior of truncating slashes that come AFTER a glob pattern in a file path that contains it is different to the behavior of truncating slashes that come before the glob pattern, whether it's defined, consistent, or purposeful.

Some findings:

That behaviour (removing some redundant slashes) is explicitly allowed by POSIX.

The  character in a pathname shall be explicitly matched by using one or more  characters in the pattern

I don't think we can infer from that text that it is required.

The only other shell I've found to do it was fish. It goes even further:
$ fish -c 'echo //hom?///stephane///.'
/home/stephane/.

None of csh, tcsh, dash, ksh93, mksh, yash, zsh, bosh, rc, es, akanga do it.
I've not tested any glob() implementation.

bash 1.13.1 (the earliest version I was able to run) already behaved like that.

ksh is the shell that is the basis for the POSIX specification of sh, and the shell bash has copied most features from, and it doesn't behave like that.

The bash reference manual states When matching a filename, the slash character must always be matched
explicitly by a slash in the pattern, but in other matching contexts it
can be matched by a special pattern character as described below, which doesn't justify that stripping of redundant /s.


All those suggest it may be an unintentional accident of implementation. It is not required by POSIX. No other Bourne/POSIX-like shell that I know does it. IMO, it's undesirable as the generated file names can end up not matching the pattern (in a case construct for instance¹).
What that means is you can't rely on that behaviour or the absence of that behaviour in a sh script. Relying on it in a bash script may not be future-proof.

¹ though there are other reasons why a glob may generate pathnames that don't match the pattern like in foo[a/b]bar*.
